# JavaScript strings outside of the BMP

Tags: javascript, unicode, utf-16, surrogate-pairs, astral-plane

BMP being [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane)

According to *JavaScript: the Good Parts*:

> JavaScript was built at a time when Unicode was a 16-bit character set, so all characters in JavaScript are 16 bits wide.

This leads me to believe that JavaScript uses UCS-2 (not UTF-16!) and can only handle characters up to U+FFFF.

Further investigation confirms this:

```
> String.fromCharCode(0x20001);
```

The `fromCharCode` method seems to only use the lowest 16 bits when returning the Unicode character. Trying to get U+20001 (CJK unified ideograph 20001) instead returns U+0001.

Question: is it at all possible to handle post-BMP characters in JavaScript?

---

2011-07-31: slide twelve from **Unicode Support Shootout: *The Good, The Bad, & the (mostly) Ugly*** covers issues related to this quite well:

[image]

Comment: If it were using UTF-16, then you would expect characters outside the basic multilingual plane to be supported using surrogate pairs. Why would you expect it to accept a 32-bit character?

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, I never thought of it that way.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan: Because JavaScript doesn't have anything resembling a "char" type and `String.fromCharCode()` returns a string it seems fair to expect it to return a string containing both code units that make up the character. I believe there will be a `String.fromCodePoint()` added to a future JavaScript standard to do exactly that.

Comment: Your question explained why I would keep getting length === 1 after using String.fromCharCode

Comment: You can now do "\u{23222}" in ES6 :D

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Depends what you mean by ‘support’. You can certainly put non-UCS-2 characters in a JS string using surrogates, and browsers will display them if they can.

But, each item in a JS string is a separate UTF-16 code unit. There is no language-level support for handling full characters: all the standard String members (`length`, `split`, `slice` etc) all deal with code units not characters, so will quite happily split surrogate pairs or hold invalid surrogate sequences.

If you want surrogate-aware methods, I'm afraid you're going to have to start writing them yourself! For example:

```
String.prototype.getCodePointLength= function() {
    return this.length-this.split(/[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]/g).length+1;
};

String.fromCodePoint= function() {
    var chars= Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    for (var i= chars.length; i-->0;) {
        var n = chars[i]-0x10000;
        if (n>=0)
            chars.splice(i, 1, 0xD800+(n>>10), 0xDC00+(n&0x3FF));
    }
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, chars);
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's a great, detailed answer.

Comment: @bobince So, technically, does JS use UCS-2 or UTF-16? UCS-2 doesn’t support characters outside the BMP, but JavaScript does if the individual surrogate halves are entered [individually](http://mothereff.in/js-escapes#1%F0%9D%8C%86) (e.g. `'\uD834\uDD1E'` for U+1D11E). But does that make it UTF-16?

Comment: @Mathias: JavaScript is UTF-16-ignorant. It gives you a sequence of 16-bit code units and lets you put what you like in it. You can store surrogates in it if you want, but you won't get any special features to handle them as characters. Whether you want to describe that as ‘using’ UCS-2 or UTF-16 is a semantic argument to which there is not one definitive answer. However regardless of language-level support in JS, other parts of the browser do support surrogates for rendering/interation in the UI, so it makes some sense to include them in JS strings.

Comment: @bobince Thanks! I looked into it a bit further and have written up my findings here: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding Feedback welcome.

Comment: (Updated fromCodePoint to match the name proposed for ECMAScript 6's support for proper Unicode. This is now effectively a polyfill.)

Comment: Changing my vote since this answer is now out of date in saying "There is no language-level support for handling full characters". There is now some language level full character support, such as `codePointAt`, `fromCodePoint`, `Array.from()`, `/u`, `for ... of`, the `...` operator. Perhaps others?

Comment: Yes, @hippietrail is right. This used to be the best answer, but times have changed. For recent browsers use the built-in browser support as [explained by Michael Allen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47963584/286685) instead.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes** — JavaScript nowadays ships with reliable tools to handle characters outside the BMP.  We should make use of them (as Stijn de Witt [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744721/?noredirect=1#comment137337773_47963584)) and not roll our own solutions.

#### `fromCodePoint`

See function `String.fromCodePoint`.

```
const ideograph = String.fromCodePoint( 0x2A6DF/*outside the BMP*/ );
console.log( ideograph );
  →
```

#### `codePointAt`

See method `String.prototype.codePointAt`.

```
const codePoint = "".codePointAt( 0 );
console.log( codePoint.toString( 16 ));
  → 2A6DF
```

#### `iterator`

See method `String.prototype[@@iterator]`.

This method returns an iterator over the code points of the string.  You can use it, for instance, to calculate a string’s length in code-point units:

```
function countCodePoints( str ) {
    let count = 0;
    const i = str[Symbol.iterator](); /* ‘The value of the "name" property
      of this method is "[Symbol.iterator]".’ — ECMA spec */
    while( !i.next().done ) ++count;
    return count; }
console.log( "".length ); // Length in 16-bit characters.
  → 2
console.log( countCodePoints( "" )); // Length in Unicode code points.
  → 1
```

Comment: This answer is underrated. It should become the accepted one I think. When native implementations are available you dont want to roll your own. Besides, the answers above modify the prototype of native `String` object. Which is frowned upon in recent years because that way of writing code makes that code influence the runtime that all other code also lives in. In other words, causes side effects. With possibly unexpected behavioural changes in otherwise completely unrelated code. Don't modify native objects. So use this code and not that from the other answers.

Comment: @Stijn de Witt: My fault if it’s underrated, it was hardly readable. Latest edit might help.

Answer (score 3):

I came to the same conclusion as bobince. If you want to work with strings containing unicode characters outside of the BMP, you have to reimplement javascript's String methods. This is because javascript counts characters as each 16-bit code value. Symbols outside of the BMP need two code values to be represented. You therefore run into a case where some symbols count as two characters and some count only as one.

I've reimplemented the following methods to treat each unicode code point as a single character: .length, .charCodeAt, .fromCharCode, .charAt, .indexOf, .lastIndexOf, .splice, and .split.

You can check it out on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y89Du/

Here's the code without comments. I tested it, but it may still have errors. Comments are welcome.

```
if (!String.prototype.ucLength) {
    String.prototype.ucLength = function() {
        // this solution was taken from 
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744721/javascript-strings-outside-of-the-bmp
        return this.length - this.split(/[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]/g).length + 1;
    };
}

if (!String.prototype.codePointAt) {
    String.prototype.codePointAt = function (ucPos) {
        if (isNaN(ucPos)){
            ucPos = 0;
        }
        var str = String(this);
        var codePoint = null;
        var pairFound = false;
        var ucIndex = -1;
        var i = 0;  
        while (i < str.length){
            ucIndex += 1;
            var code = str.charCodeAt(i);
            var next = str.charCodeAt(i + 1);
            pairFound = (0xD800 <= code && code <= 0xDBFF && 0xDC00 <= next && next <= 0xDFFF);
            if (ucIndex == ucPos){
                codePoint = pairFound ? ((code - 0xD800) * 0x400) + (next - 0xDC00) + 0x10000 : code;
                break;
            } else{
                i += pairFound ? 2 : 1;
            }
        }
        return codePoint;
    };
}

if (!String.fromCodePoint) {
    String.fromCodePoint = function () {
        var strChars = [], codePoint, offset, codeValues, i;
        for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
            codePoint = arguments[i];
            offset = codePoint - 0x10000;
            if (codePoint > 0xFFFF){
                codeValues = [0xD800 + (offset >> 10), 0xDC00 + (offset & 0x3FF)];
            } else{
                codeValues = [codePoint];
            }
            strChars.push(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, codeValues));
        }
        return strChars.join("");
    };
}

if (!String.prototype.ucCharAt) {
    String.prototype.ucCharAt = function (ucIndex) {
        var str = String(this);
        var codePoint = str.codePointAt(ucIndex);
        var ucChar = String.fromCodePoint(codePoint);
        return ucChar;
    };
}

if (!String.prototype.ucIndexOf) {
    String.prototype.ucIndexOf = function (searchStr, ucStart) {
        if (isNaN(ucStart)){
            ucStart = 0;
        }
        if (ucStart < 0){
            ucStart = 0;
        }
        var str = String(this);
        var strUCLength = str.ucLength();
        searchStr = String(searchStr);
        var ucSearchLength = searchStr.ucLength();
        var i = ucStart;
        while (i < strUCLength){
            var ucSlice = str.ucSlice(i,i+ucSearchLength);
            if (ucSlice == searchStr){
                return i;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return -1;
    };
}

if (!String.prototype.ucLastIndexOf) {
    String.prototype.ucLastIndexOf = function (searchStr, ucStart) {
        var str = String(this);
        var strUCLength = str.ucLength();
        if (isNaN(ucStart)){
            ucStart = strUCLength - 1;
        }
        if (ucStart >= strUCLength){
            ucStart = strUCLength - 1;
        }
        searchStr = String(searchStr);
        var ucSearchLength = searchStr.ucLength();
        var i = ucStart;
        while (i >= 0){
            var ucSlice = str.ucSlice(i,i+ucSearchLength);
            if (ucSlice == searchStr){
                return i;
            }
            i--;
        }
        return -1;
    };
}

if (!String.prototype.ucSlice) {
    String.prototype.ucSlice = function (ucStart, ucStop) {
        var str = String(this);
        var strUCLength = str.ucLength();
        if (isNaN(ucStart)){
            ucStart = 0;
        }
        if (ucStart < 0){
            ucStart = strUCLength + ucStart;
            if (ucStart < 0){ ucStart = 0;}
        }
        if (typeof(ucStop) == 'undefined'){
            ucStop = strUCLength - 1;
        }
        if (ucStop < 0){
            ucStop = strUCLength + ucStop;
            if (ucStop < 0){ ucStop = 0;}
        }
        var ucChars = [];
        var i = ucStart;
        while (i < ucStop){
            ucChars.push(str.ucCharAt(i));
            i++;
        }
        return ucChars.join("");
    };
}

if (!String.prototype.ucSplit) {
    String.prototype.ucSplit = function (delimeter, limit) {
        var str = String(this);
        var strUCLength = str.ucLength();
        var ucChars = [];
        if (delimeter == ''){
            for (var i = 0; i < strUCLength; i++){
                ucChars.push(str.ucCharAt(i));
            }
            ucChars = ucChars.slice(0, 0 + limit);
        } else{
            ucChars = str.split(delimeter, limit);
        }
        return ucChars;
    };
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for releasing into public domain. You, sir/madam, are a gentleman/woman and a scholar.

Comment: `ucCharAt` seems to be broken. `"".ucCharAt(0)` returns the correct value but change the 0 to a 1 and it returns gibberish. Change it to 2 and it returns the second (instead of the first) symbol. So to get to the last symbol, you have to call `ucCharAt(8)` which is larger than the string's ucLength.

Comment: Don't modify native objects. Use the built-in browser support as [explained by Michael Allen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47963584/286685) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Although support to non-BMP characters directly in source documents is optional according to the ECMAScript standard, modern browsers let you use them. Naturally, the document encoding must be properly declared, and for most practical purposes you would need to use the UTF-8 encoding. Moreover, you need an editor that can handle UTF-8, and you need some input method(s); see e.g. my [Full Unicode Input](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/fui.html8) utility.

Using suitable tools and settings, you can write `var foo = ''`.

The non-BMP characters will be internally represented as surrogate pairs, so each non-BMP character counts as 2 in the string length.

Answer (score 0):

Using `for (c of this)` instruction, one can make various computations on a string that contains non-BMP characters. For instance, to compute the string length, and to get the nth character of the string:

```
String.prototype.magicLength = function()
{
    var c, k;
    k = 0;
    for (c of this) // iterate each char of this
    {
        k++;
    }
    return k;
}

String.prototype.magicCharAt = function(n)
{
    var c, k;
    k = 0;
    for (c of this) // iterate each char of this
    {
        if (k == n) return c + "";
        k++;
    }
    return "";
}
```