# How do I replace emoji characters from my text

Tags: javascript

I am scanning my text and converting text to links. How do I replace the emoji chars from the link

for example `pic.twitter.com/OIWBW3lnYBnY`

I want to replace it with  `pic.twitter.com/OIWBW3lnYBnY` Note the space after the character

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know the emoji format, but you could do a copy paste like this

`"pic.twitter.com/OIWBW3lnYBnY".replace('',' ')`

Comment: Or see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22006218/replace-emoji-unicode-symbol-using-regexp-in-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885879/javascript-and-string-manipulation-w-utf-16-surrogate-pairs see also this for why this is so damned hard

Answer (score -1):

```
window.onload = function() {


//this is the code
var x='pic.twitter.com/OIWBW3lnYBnY';
//and this
var emoji_chars='-- ';
var y=x.replace(x.substring(0,4),emoji_chars);
// or (0,4) change (0,2)

//example
    document.body.innerHTML=y;
};
```

Comment: Hmm I cannot use this because the special chars will not always be the clapping hands one, It could be anything

Comment: Please wait a few minutes