# How to get all unique characters represantations out of an utf-8 string in Firefox 70?

Tags: javascript, string, firefox, utf-8, unique

The result of the following code is only `‍♂️` , where I want to find all the unique graphic represationations shown in the Firefox output that I copied to the var a originally. (Basically the code should show the original `a` string as output.)

How to do that?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<script>
var a = '‍♂️ ‍♂️ ‍♂️       ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍  ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍  ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍  ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍  ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍   ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍  ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍  ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍  ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍   ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍  ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍  ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍  ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍        ';
var b = [...new Set([...a])];
var c = b.join('');
function init() { document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = c; }
</script>
</head><body onload="init()">
<span id="result"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885879/javascript-and-string-manipulation-w-utf-16-surrogate-pairs

Comment: Yeah well, emojis are composed of multiple unicodepoints, so JS has to represent them as those. I'm really curious for a solution (cause I can't think of one), so if this has no answer in a few days I'd raise a bounty :)