# Get grapheme character count in javascript strings?

Tags: javascript, unicode, grapheme

I'm trying to get the length of a javascript string in user-visible graphemes, ie ignoring combining characters (and surrogate pairs?). Is this possible, and if so, how would I go about it?

We're using the dojo toolkit on our project, but any general javascript solution would be great.

Comment: Answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3744721/1352254 include the useful info that javascript uses UCS-2 instead of UTF-16, and indicate that this won't be possible.

Comment: It will be possible, it just won't be easy because you'll have to deal with some low-level Unicode issues.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531751/how-can-i-split-a-string-containing-emoji-into-an-array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I split a string containing emoji into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531751/how-can-i-split-a-string-containing-emoji-into-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the combining characters, look at the [Derived Combining Class](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/extracted/DerivedCombiningClass.txt) that lists all combining characters (among others). Since you're just interested in counting, you could just nuke them out -- leaves you with a slightly closer estimation.

In the post linked to by Angus, [JavaScript strings outside of the BMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744721/javascript-strings-outside-of-the-bmp#3759300) shows code to deal with surrogates. But the code actually does the contrary of what you want -- it splits the 0x10000+ codepoints into two codepoints. As far as JS is concerned it's one codepoint -- albeit a truncated one. Who cares? You're counting them, not displaying...

BUT, there's another category of codepoints you might want to deal with too, the non-printable characters. Anything under 0x20 of course, but there's plenty of others -- look at the 0x2000 range for instance. These are not visible either and should not be included in your count.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I didn't notice at the time that the linked question had example code, I had looked over it and thought JS just couldn't handle the low-level string stuff that would be necessary.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a pure JavaScript library that does just that:

https://github.com/orling/grapheme-splitter

It implements the Unicode UAX-29 standard in all its edge cases that you're likely to miss in a home-brew solution, like non-Latin diacritics, Hangul (Korean) jamo characters, emoji, multiple combining marks, etc.

Answer (score 9):

Use [`Intl.Segmenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Segmenter).

> The **`Intl.Segmenter`** object enables locale-sensitive text segmentation, enabling you to get meaningful items (graphemes, words or sentences) from a string.

```js
[...new Intl.Segmenter().segment('️‍⚧️️‍‍❤️‍')].length;
//=> 3

"️‍⚧️️‍‍❤️‍".length
//=> 24

[..."️‍⚧️️‍‍❤️‍"].length
//=> 17
```

As of March 2023 `Intl.Segmenter` is available in Node, Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox ([see availability table](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_intl_segmenter_segmenter), [polyfill available here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/intl-segmenter-polyfill)).

Answer (score 0):

This open-source CoffeeScript implementation seems to work decently enough: https://github.com/devongovett/grapheme-breaker (if only it wasn't CS )