# How to split emojis that contain flags without the flag breaking into 2 characters in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, formulas

This is my initial string:

I used a not so elegant way to break up the emojis.

```
=if(len(I88) = 4, REGEXEXTRACT(I88,"(.+?)\s*(.+?)"),if(len(I88) = 6, REGEXEXTRACT(I88,"(.+?)\s*(.+?)\s*(.+?)"),if(len(I88) = 8, REGEXEXTRACT(I88,"(.+?)\s*(.+?)\s*(.+?)\s*(.+?)"),if(len(I88) = 10, REGEXEXTRACT(I88,"(.+?)\s*(.+?)\s*(.+?)\s*(.+?)\s*(.+?)"), REGEXEXTRACT(I88,"\s*(.+?)" )))))
```

The result is 4 columns instead of 3: this is what it looks like

```
  |  |   |
```

I left the pipes to indicate a separate column

What I want is this:

```
 |  |
```

Comment: This is a problem in JS ES5 regex syntax. Instead of a `.`, you need to use `(?:[\0-\t\x0B\f\x0E-\u2027\u202A-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF](?![\uDC00-\uDFFF])|(?:[^\uD800-\uDBFF]|^)[\uDC00-\uDFFF])`. Also, you cannot use `(.+?)` at the end of the pattern, it will match nothing.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Actually the problem is related with the implementation of [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2) in Google Sheets but the solution requires the use of JavaScript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Short answer

To correctly separate the three emoticons we need to use a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions). Fortunaly there are JavaScript libraries that could be used for this like [the one](https://github.com/orling/grapheme-splitter) shared in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31230357/1595451) by [Orlin Giorgiev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1472151/orlin-georgiev) to [Get grapheme character count in javascript strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287887/get-grapheme-character-count-in-javascript-strings)

## Explanation

The OP formula is returning four elements instead of three because Google Sheets built-in functions requires four "characters" (actually they are code points) that need more than 4 hexadecimal digits to represent them. Each set of "characters" to represent emoticons are called "astral code points".

From https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode

> Astral code points are pretty easy to recognize: if you need more than 4 hexadecimal digits to represent the code point, it’s an astral code point.

---

> Internally, JavaScript [as well Google Sheets built-in functions] represents astral symbols as [surrogate pairs](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding#surrogate-pairs), and [it exposes the separate surrogate halves as separate “characters”](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding). If you represent the symbols using nothing but ECMAScript 5-compatible escape sequences, you’ll see that two escapes are needed for each astral symbol. This is confusing, because humans generally think in terms of Unicode symbols or graphemes instead.

### Custom function

```
function SPLITGRAPHEMES(string) {
  var splitter = new GraphemeSplitter();
  return splitter.splitGraphemes(string); 
}
```

NOTE: Don't forget to include the [referred JavaScript library](https://github.com/orling/grapheme-splitter)

### Syntax

Assume that A1 contains [image: emoticons]. To split the three emoticons in a 1 x 3 array use the following formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLITGRAPHEMES(A1))
```

Note: In Windows the emoticons () in this Q&A doesn't look the same as in Chrome OS, so a image was used in the above paragraph.