# How to use five digit long Unicode characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, unicode, ecmascript-harmony

In JavaScript I can do this:

```
foo = "\u2669" // 1/4 note
```

But I can't do this

```
foo = "\u1D15D" // full note  -five hex digits
```

It will be interpreted as "\u1D15" followed by "D"

Are there any workarounds for this?

UPDATE 2012-07-09: [The proposal for ECMAScript Harmony](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts) now includes support for all Unicode characters.

Comment: The context is this small application about musical notes in Canvas that a student of mine is attempting: http://keryx.se/dev/html5/noter/noter.html (Nothing fancy. He has only programmed for just 2 months, a few hours a week.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript strings outside of the BMP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744721/javascript-strings-outside-of-the-bmp).

Comment: [Got this on Twitter](https://twitter.com/#!/zcorpan/status/202752353986813952): "You have to use surrogate pairs"

Comment: Javascript is still stuck in Unicode 1 from before 1995. It is miserable for modern text processing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the [MDN documentation for fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode), they note that javascript will only naturally handle characters up to 0xFFFF.  However, they also have an implementation of a fixed method for fromCharCode that may do what you want (reproduced below):

```
function fixedFromCharCode (codePt) {
    if (codePt > 0xFFFF) {
        codePt -= 0x10000;
        return String.fromCharCode(0xD800 + (codePt >> 10), 0xDC00 + (codePt & 0x3FF));
    }
    else {
        return String.fromCharCode(codePt);
    }
}

foo = fixedFromCharCode(0x1D15D);
```

Comment: If you have the correct font installed doing `String.fromCharCode( 0x01D15D )` will render you that char.

Comment: Do you have an example of a font for which that works?  I'd love to see that fromCharCode now supports codes outside the BMP, but everything I read today seemed to indicate it doesn't.

(Also see Frédéric Hamidi's comment above)

Comment: I just did a quick test in opera and it spat out the "can't render char"-character. So that lead me to believe that you need the font actually render the character.

Comment: That’s a horrible hack. Not being able to specify the full range of Unicode code points is a severe hardship. Javascript is still stuck in the pre-1995 world.  It’s a scandal.

Comment: Sorry for being late answering this. I need to get my student to install an appropriate font first, for him to try it. I will get back in a day or two and give credit if it works.

Comment: @Dre String.fromCharCode( 0x01D15D ) by itself does not work. At least not in Firefox - which is my only tested browser so far.

Comment: Downloaded the [Code2001 font](http://font.downloadatoz.com/download,33552,code2001-font-for-linux.html) and ran tests. fixedFromCharCode works.

Comment: Ref: [The algorithm explained at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF)

Answer (score 32):

Try putting the unicode between curly braces: `'\u{1D15D}'`.

Comment: This is the way to go! More read up here: https://dmitripavlutin.com/what-every-javascript-developer-should-know-about-unicode/

Comment: This doesn't work in regular expressions I don't think, unfortunately. I wish!

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, you can simply use `String.fromCodePoint()`, as documented in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint). For instance:

```js
> String.fromCodePoint(0x1f0a1)
""
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a little checking and it appears that there is no full note near `0x2669`. ([table of unicode chars](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/2000-2FFF))

Although using `0x01D15D` does give me a unknown unicode character this could be because I don't have a music font though. Javascript will try to parse as byte as it can and `0x1D15D` is 2.5 bytes padding it with a `0` will make it 3 and parsable.

Also this was quite handy: unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D100.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
function fromOutsideBMP(cp) {
// 0x01D120
  var x=cp-0x10000;
  var top10=parseInt("11111111110000000000",2);
  var end10=parseInt("1111111111",2);
  var part1=(x&top10)/1024+0xD800;
  var part2=(x&end10)+0xDC00;
  var s=String.fromCharCode(part1)+String.fromCharCode(part2);
  return s;
}
```

Example:

```
> fromOutsideBMP(0x01d122)
  ""
>
```