# How to convert digits to their unicode bolded version?

Tags: javascript, unicode

I would like to bold some character in a javascript confirm popup. As you can't use html/css there, and extending a bit the solution to [underline with the dedicated unicode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470817/format-the-text-in-javascript-alert-box#17471151), I thought I might simply replace each [digit with its bolded unicode counterpart](https://unicode-table.com/fr/blocks/mathematical-alphanumeric-symbols/), and as [they are five digit long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615409/how-to-use-five-digit-long-unicode-characters-in-javascript#10615607) (ranging from 1D7CE to , 1D7D7), I came with the following code:

```
function bold(number) {
  return number.
    replace(/0/, String.fromCharCode(0x1D7CE)).
    replace(/1/, String.fromCharCode(0x1D7CF)).
    replace(/2/, String.fromCharCode(0x1D7D0)).
    replace(/3/, String.fromCharCode(0x1D7D1)).
    replace(/4/, String.fromCharCode(0x1D7D2)).
    replace(/5/, String.fromCharCode(0x1D7D3)).
    replace(/6/, String.fromCharCode(0x1D7D4)).
    replace(/7/, String.fromCharCode(0x1D7D5)).
    replace(/8/, String.fromCharCode(0x1D7D6)).
    replace(/9/, String.fromCharCode(0x1D7D7));
}
```

But I must misunderstand something, as for example `1` is replaced with `ퟏ` (D7CE).

What might be a working solution?

Comment: `String.fromCharCode(0x01D7CE)` returns
`"ퟎ"` only!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this simplified implementation:

```js
function bold(number) {
  return number.replace(/\d/g, (c) => String.fromCodePoint(0x1D79E + c.charCodeAt(0)));
}

console.log(bold('abc 0123456789 def'));
```

This uses [`String.fromCodePoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint) which supports the full range of unicode, [unlike `String.fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt#Description).

This simplification takes advantage of the fact that numbers and bolded numbers both take up a consecutive run of 10 unicode points, separated by a distance of `0x1D79E`.

Comment: How do I use this to make any character bold?

Comment: @kittu you would need to locate other ranges of bold characters in the unicode pages. Basically, every type of character that has a normal and bold equivalent in unicode, you'd need to implement separately.