# How to count emoji in a bunch text react native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobile

I'm new to react-native, I want to analyze my text in the following criteria

I have my string like this

`happy Morning Tuesday ðŸ˜œâœŒðŸ», Today I'm had my breakfast`

In this string this one is emoji Unicode character`ðŸ˜œâœŒðŸ»`.I want to do the following analysis

1. Total number of emojis,
2. count number of times used for every emoji

Can you help me, I want to do in react native, can you suggest any packages or any references for me

Comment: Can you provide some example data and the result you expect?

Comment: I updated my questions, now you can check

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect emoji using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862256/how-to-detect-emoji-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following [library](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/emoji-regex)

if you dont want to use any third party library try

```
function getEmojiChars(text) {

console.log(text.match(/\ud83c[\udf00-\udfff]|\ud83d[\udc00-\ude4f]|\ud83d[\ude80-\udeff]/g))  ;
}
```

also refer the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862256/how-to-detect-emoji-using-javascript)

Comment: Thank You Rizwan, I will check this package