# Is there any way to validate emojis without using regex with an unicode flag?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, regex, validation

(:

I'm working on some input validation with js and one of the criteria is that the user is not allowed to input emojis.

This is the code that I was using originally is:

```
emojiValidation: function (userInput) {
   if (new RegExp("\\p{Extended_Pictographic}", 'u').test(userInput)) {
      return true;

   }
   
   return false;
```

This function is being called from a js file but the application is built using asp.net

The problem I'm facing is that IE does not recognise the Unicode flag, so is there an IE-friendly way to detect emojis?

[IE console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sictg.png)

Thank you!

Comment: Related [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-regex)?

Comment: I posted the ES5 compliant pattern [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69115223/3832970) that detects all currently supported emojis.