# How to print an div with emoji "❤️" to pdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm write a app to print some texts to pdf, but when I put a emoji like ❤️ and I try to print this using window.print, the emojis lost format, lost colors.

[image]

why this happens? what can I do to print this div with the emojis?

Comment: Emojis are UTF characters. Hence, different programs interpret them differently. You will need an emoji "font" or a reader than incorporates Emoji fonts. 
But the best way would be to replace all Emojis with images, (i.e. the old school way) before generating the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use @font-face to **embed** a font that contains emoji (I think that is quite rare, but this seems a contender: https://emojisymbols.com/).
2. Use @font-face to **embed** an icon font and wrap all emoji in spans that use that specific icon font.
3. Write javascript* that replaces all emoji with images just before you fire the print command, like this:

   ```
   onclick="replaceAllEmojiWithImages(); window.print();"
   ```

*The javascript function can be derived from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64007175/2397550