# How do I detect an emoji in a Snowflake VARCHAR?

Tags: javascript, sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, emoji

I have a 1B row table of chat messages with a max-sized VARCHAR column for the raw message text. How do I -

1. Select just the rows that contain 1 or more emoji characters
2. Efficiently filter out rows without emoji (if needed to improve performance)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. 
Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 5):

Combining the knowledge shared by Lukasz and Greg, plus discovering an additional hidden character, I can present this solution:

- 1 JS UDF that detects the presence of emojis.
- 1 JS UDF that detects if the string is only emojis.

```sql
create or replace function has_emoji(X text)
returns boolean
language javascript
as $$
return /\p{Extended_Pictographic}/u.test(X);
$$;

create or replace function only_emoji(X text)
returns boolean
language javascript
as $$
return /^[\p{Extended_Pictographic}\p{Emoji_Component}]+$/u.test(X);
$$;
```

Sample use:

```sql
with data as (
  select $1 t
  from values('❄️'),('❄️ is the data ☁️'),('no emoji')
)

select *, has_emoji(t), only_emoji(t)
from data
;
```

[image]

--

Some research:

- `'❄️'.replace(/\p{Extended_Pictographic}/ug, '')` returns `''`
- but `'❄️'.replace(/\p{Extended_Pictographic}/ug, '')` is not equal to `''`
- Turns out there are hidden characters that still need to be replaced, and matched by `Emoji_Component`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using Snowflake's [JavaScript User Defined Function](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/javascript/udf-javascript-scalar-functions.html#scalar-javascript-udfs):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION EMOJI_TEST (STR VARCHAR)
  RETURNS VARCHAR
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
  AS $$
  return (/\p{Emoji}/u.test(STR));
  $$
  ;
```

Query:

```
WITH cte(col) AS (
    SELECT ''   UNION ALL
    SELECT 'text' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'text '
)
SELECT col, EMOJI_TEST(col)
FROM cte
-- WHERE EMOJI_TEST(col)::BOOLEAN
```

Output:

[image]

Related: [How to detect emoji using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64007175/5070879)

Comment: That works, but I'm having trouble detecting only emoji. If `/\p{Emoji}/u.test('❄️')` testing for emoji works, why not `/^\p{Emoji}$/u.test('❄️')` for only emoji?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa It is strange ,the beginning of string works `/^\p{Emoji}/u.test('❄️')` so it is somehow connected with end of string and `$`(though that works for exact match `/^❄️$/u.test('❄️')`

Comment: Indeed... I had an answer similar to this one, but then got stuck with the "only emoji" requirement

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Maybe you could rewrite it as Java UDF :)

Comment: JS makes it so easy with `\p{Emoji}` tho..

Comment: Although the OP is asking about "emoji" the specification has a *lot* of things in it that most people don't think of as emojis: https://unicode.org/Public/emoji/11.0/emoji-data.txt.  For example using `{Emoji}` it will return true for #, the expression "Flowers 123" etc. It would be more accurate to change the RegEx code to `{Extended_Pictographic}`

Comment: Extended_Pictographic + Emoji_Component finally solved the mystery... https://stackoverflow.com/a/69936510/132438