# How to preventDefault() textInput event?

Tags: javascript

I have a textarea on my page. If user on Windows (not sure about Mac behavior though) will open built-in Emoji menu (`Win + .`) in that textarea and click on any emoji, the `textInput` event will be fired. I need to, somehow, prevent default behavior for this event, which is inserting an emoji to the input, and resolve emoji insertion on my side. However, `event.preventDefault()` doesn't work in this case. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't catch the event, instead, detect the emoji in the input, delete it, and replace it with any custom behavior

Comment: @mousetail that's interesting approach, will see into that. The one problem I can see so far is how to detect an emoji?

Comment: That's a completely different problem that has plenty of answers on this site

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862256/how-to-detect-emoji-using-javascript

Comment: Thank you! Anyway, I am still wondering if there is a way to just prevent inserting emojis. If I want to disable it for some input, I should be able to do that easily, without writing a ton of additional logic with detecting and deleting emojis

Comment: Emoji is just a specific case. The question is about preventing `textInput` event from doing its thing

Comment: And this is crucial, because in windows we not only have Emojis in that menu, but also GIFs and applying them in inputs causes stupid bugs

Comment: Reopened. Please change the text of the question to match your requirements. The one you asked has been handled using a workaround but I will be interested in seeing how you will preventDefault on a process that does not trigger an event you can prevent.

Comment: _"The question is about preventing textInput event from doing its thing"_ - when you say "textInput" event, you mean the actual `input` event? That is not cancelable, so no, you can not prevent the insertion of anything via _that_.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can handle the emoji interface using preventDefault.

We cannot detect the combination of event.key==="Meta" and "."

Here is how to handle it after the fact:

```js
const re = /\p{Emoji}|\p{Emoji_Presentation}|\p{Extended_Pictographic}/ug; // can be extended
document.getElementById('myField').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  const val = this.value;
  this.value = val.replace(re,"");
})
```

```html
<textarea id="myField"></textarea>
```

the script above is from combining the information from the answers below

- [How to detect emoji using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862256/how-to-detect-emoji-using-javascript)
- [What is the difference between {Emoji_Presentation} and {Extended_Pictographic}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70401560/what-is-the-difference-between-emoji-presentation-and-extended-pictographic)