# How to ignore this error? As in stop it from sending

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I made a feature in my discord bot to react to emojis with the same emoji, but when someone sends a message that isnt an emoji, it sends this error (it doesnt stop the bot, it just annoys me and floods the console)

Here it is:

```js
client.on("message", message => {
  try {
    message.react(message.content);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('')
  }
});
```

I tried looking for a way to check if the message is an emoji or not before running `message.react(message.content);`.

But i didn't find a result.

And here's the error:
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Emoji

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect emoji using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862256/how-to-detect-emoji-using-javascript) or this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757193/find-out-if-character-in-string-is-emoji](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757193/find-out-if-character-in-string-is-emoji)

Comment: I want to know how I can make the error not show up at all, so when I encounter another error that doesn't cause problems, I can fix it. And the other question is for swift, I want Node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ignore an error you can add `.catch((err) => {})` to your code, for example:

```js
message.react("").catch((err) => {})
```

Comment: Okay, 1 second, I'll try that.

Comment: It worked! I cant believe it was that simple, thanks.