How to check if a string contains emojis in Java
I want to use Java language to identify whether a string type data contains emoji.
I use the "[\ud83c\udc00-\ud83c\udfff]|[\ud83d\udc00-\ud83d\udfff]|[\u2600-\u27ff]" regular to find a string has a emoji ,but a find it is not comprehensive，Some emoticons cannot be identified. Do you have a more comprehensive regular expression to solve this problem。like  emoji can‘t match with my regular.

If you are bound to regex, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862256/how-to-detect-emoji-using-javascript

since Java 21: Character.isEmoji(int) or Character.isEmojiPresentation(int) see javadoc -- regular expression \p{IsEmoji}

If before 21, you might have to make your own detector using something like this. You'll need to use codepoints, not chars

I use java 8, and hasn't Character.isEmoji(int)

Unless you have a very good reason for doing so, you should update as soon as possible

Can you try the JEmoji library?
Gradle Kotlin DSL
implementation("net.fellbaum:jemoji:1.4.0")

Maven
 <dependency>
     <groupId>net.fellbaum</groupId>
     <artifactId>jemoji</artifactId>
     <version>1.4.0</version>
  </dependency>

Example 1: Check if the provided string contains an emoji
boolean test4= EmojiManager.containsEmoji("like  emoji");//true
boolean test1= EmojiManager.containsEmoji("Hello  World");//true
boolean test2= EmojiManager.containsEmoji("This string contains beans ");//true
boolean test3= EmojiManager.containsEmoji("Hello World");//false

Example 2: Check if the provided string is an emoji
boolean isEmoji=EmojiManager.isEmoji("");//true

Example 3: Extract all emojis from a string in the order they appear
List<Emoji> emojis=EmojiManager.extractEmojisInOrder("Hello  World "); // [, ]

Fore more information please visit https://github.com/felldo/JEmoji

If you are using Java 21 you will be able to use Character#isEmoji(int)
