# how to show emoticon taken from Instagram API

Tags: html, css

When using the Instagram API, the response that I got when the string contains emoji's and new lines is the following string of text:

```
\ud83c\udf00 New ReadyStock \ud83c\udf00 EAR-EL380 : Rp 55,000\n\nOrder thru : BBM \/ LINE\n\n#premiumaccessories #accessories #marpaungs #jewelry #jualanku #jualankaka #trustedseller
```

For some reason webstagram is able to show this nicely on their website as can be seen [here](http://websta.me/n/marpaungs). How do I parse this string along with the new lines and stuff so I can get something formatted correctly with the new lines and everything?

[image]

Comment: Might answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/12824140/1342440

Comment: @Brian that posts specifically shows how you can remove it and not show it appropriately

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? Any help will be appreciated