# How to remove ⭕️ and ♛ emoji from the beginning of the string PHP?

Tags: php, regex, emoji

How to remove ⭕️ and ♛ emoji from the beginning of the string PHP?
Please note that I only want to remove ⭕️ and ♛ emoji, NOT all the emoji.

For example:-

If the string is `⭕️ ABC 123 XYZ 789` 
then it should look `ABC 123 XYZ 789`   after removal of emoji ♛ from the beginning of the string.

I tried `preg_replace("⭕️", "", $string) and str_replace("⭕️", "", $string)` but does not work at all.

Comment: So, what have you tried and what does not work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Removing a string is not the same as moving a set of characters so I don't think that duplicate really fits.

Comment: See `$str = preg_replace('/^' . preg_quote($prefix, '/') . '/', '', $str);` in the linked question. `$prefix` is the `(⭕️|♛)`. Probably, the `u` modifier will be required.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Or you just use `trim()` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for regex here, just use [`ltrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php):

```
$str = '⭕️ and ♛ emoji from t';
var_dump(ltrim($str, '⭕️♛'));
```

Result:

> string(21) " and ♛ emoji from t"

An [example](https://3v4l.org/F2S6B).

Comment: I do get the downvote for answering a low-quality question, but deleting a correct - and by far the simplest - answer that does not appear in the duplicate is just silly.

Comment: well that sure wasn't mine

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Never doubted that :-)

Answer (score -1):

Looks to already be answered here:
[PHP : writing a simple removeEmoji function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807176/php-writing-a-simple-removeemoji-function)

Because its just those two emojis, you only have to search on those two unicodes (  U+265B and U+2B55)  just do a replace on those characters instead of a whole regex.

Comment: shouldn't you have flagged as a possible duplicate instead? You're plagiarizing on an existing Q&A.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew so that gives them the right for plagia? come on; I think you should know about this. You've been here long enough. Edit: you deleted that comment I was responding to.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner sorry to of offended, was not my intent.  Kind of harsh though, as I just now noticed i have the ability to flag posts for duplicate now.  I didn't have those rep points < hour ago...

Comment: No offense taken. But what do you mean by "harsh"? That isn't my downvote you received btw.