# Remove emojis from string

Tags: php, emoji

I'm using imagettftext function on my code and I found out that emojis can't be used.
I tried lots of solutions, but I can't find out a way to completely remove them

```
$string = remove_emoji("Test⭐️");
function remove_emoji($text){
      return preg_replace('/[\x{1F3F4}](?:\x{E0067}\x{E0062}\x{E0077}\x{E006C}\x{E0073}\x{E007F})|[\x{1F3F4}](?:\x{E0067}\x{E0062}\x{E0073}\x{E0063}\x{E0074}\x{E007F})|[\x{1F3F4}](?:\x{E0067}\x{E0062}\x{E0065}\x{E006E}\x{E0067}\x{E007F})|[\x{1F3F4}](?:\x{200D}\x{2620}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F3F3}](?:\x{FE0F}\x{200D}\x{1F308})|[\x{0023}\x{002A}\x{0030}\x{0031}\x{0032}\x{0033}\x{0034}\x{0035}\x{0036}\x{0037}\x{0038}\x{0039}](?:\x{FE0F}\x{20E3})|[\x{1F441}](?:\x{FE0F}\x{200D}\x{1F5E8}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F467}\x{200D}\x{1F467})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F467}\x{200D}\x{1F466})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F467})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F466}\x{200D}\x{1F466})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F466})|[\x{1F468}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F468}\x{200D}\x{1F467}\x{200D}\x{1F467})|[\x{1F468}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F468}\x{200D}\x{1F466}\x{200D}\x{1F466})|[\x{1F468}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F468}\x{200D}\x{1F467}\x{200D}\x{1F466})|[\x{1F468}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F468}\x{200D}\x{1F467})|[\x{1F468}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F468}\x{200D}\x{1F466})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F469}\x{200D}\x{1F467}\x{200D}\x{1F467})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F469}\x{200D}\x{1F466}\x{200D}\x{1F466})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F469}\x{200D}\x{1F467}\x{200D}\x{1F466})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F469}\x{200D}\x{1F467})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F469}\x{200D}\x{1F466})|[\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{2764}\x{FE0F}\x{200D}\x{1F469})|[\x{1F469}\x{1F468}](?:\x{200D}\x{2764}\x{FE0F}\x{200D}\x{1F468})|[\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{2764}\x{FE0F}\x{200D}\x{1F48B}\x{200D}\x{1F469})|[\x{1F469}\x{1F468}](?:\x{200D}\x{2764}\x{FE0F}\x{200D}\x{1F48B}\x{200D}\x{1F468})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F9B3})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F9B3})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F9B3})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F9B3})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F9B3})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F9B3})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F9B2})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F9B2})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F9B2})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F9B2})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F9B2})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F9B2})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F9B1})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F9B1})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F9B1})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F9B1})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F9B1})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F9B1})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F9B0})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F9B0})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F9B0})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F9B0})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F9B0})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F9B0})|[\x{1F575}\x{1F3CC}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}](?:\x{FE0F}\x{200D}\x{2640}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F575}\x{1F3CC}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}](?:\x{FE0F}\x{200D}\x{2642}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F473}\x{1F471}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{2640}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F473}\x{1F471}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{2640}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F473}\x{1F471}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{2640}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F473}\x{1F471}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{2640}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F473}\x{1F471}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{2640}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F46E}\x{1F9B8}\x{1F9B9}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F473}\x{1F471}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F9DE}\x{1F9DF}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F46F}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93C}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}](?:\x{200D}\x{2640}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F473}\x{1F471}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{2642}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F473}\x{1F471}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{2642}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F473}\x{1F471}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{2642}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F473}\x{1F471}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{2642}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F473}\x{1F471}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{2642}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F46E}\x{1F9B8}\x{1F9B9}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F473}\x{1F471}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F9DE}\x{1F9DF}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F46F}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93C}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}](?:\x{200D}\x{2642}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F692})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F692})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F692})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F692})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F692})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F692})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F680})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F680})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F680})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F680})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F680})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F680})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{2708}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{2708}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{2708}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{2708}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{2708}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{2708}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F3A8})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F3A8})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F3A8})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F3A8})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F3A8})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F3A8})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F3A4})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F3A4})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F3A4})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F3A4})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F3A4})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F3A4})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F4BB})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F4BB})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F4BB})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F4BB})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F4BB})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F4BB})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F52C})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F52C})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F52C})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F52C})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F52C})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F52C})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F4BC})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F4BC})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F4BC})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F4BC})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F4BC})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F4BC})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F3ED})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F3ED})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F3ED})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F3ED})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F3ED})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F3ED})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F527})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F527})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F527})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F527})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F527})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F527})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F373})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F373})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F373})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F373})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F373})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F373})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F33E})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F33E})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F33E})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F33E})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F33E})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F33E})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{2696}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{2696}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{2696}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{2696}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{2696}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{2696}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F3EB})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F3EB})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F3EB})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F3EB})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F3EB})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F3EB})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F393})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F393})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F393})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F393})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F393})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{1F393})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{2695}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{2695}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{2695}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{2695}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{2695}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}](?:\x{200D}\x{2695}\x{FE0F})|[\x{1F476}\x{1F9D2}\x{1F466}\x{1F467}\x{1F9D1}\x{1F468}\x{1F469}\x{1F9D3}\x{1F474}\x{1F475}\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F934}\x{1F478}\x{1F473}\x{1F472}\x{1F9D5}\x{1F9D4}\x{1F471}\x{1F935}\x{1F470}\x{1F930}\x{1F931}\x{1F47C}\x{1F385}\x{1F936}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F483}\x{1F57A}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F6C0}\x{1F6CC}\x{1F574}\x{1F3C7}\x{1F3C2}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}\x{1F933}\x{1F4AA}\x{1F9B5}\x{1F9B6}\x{1F448}\x{1F449}\x{261D}\x{1F446}\x{1F595}\x{1F447}\x{270C}\x{1F91E}\x{1F596}\x{1F918}\x{1F919}\x{1F590}\x{270B}\x{1F44C}\x{1F44D}\x{1F44E}\x{270A}\x{1F44A}\x{1F91B}\x{1F91C}\x{1F91A}\x{1F44B}\x{1F91F}\x{270D}\x{1F44F}\x{1F450}\x{1F64C}\x{1F932}\x{1F64F}\x{1F485}\x{1F442}\x{1F443}](?:\x{1F3FF})|[\x{1F476}\x{1F9D2}\x{1F466}\x{1F467}\x{1F9D1}\x{1F468}\x{1F469}\x{1F9D3}\x{1F474}\x{1F475}\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F934}\x{1F478}\x{1F473}\x{1F472}\x{1F9D5}\x{1F9D4}\x{1F471}\x{1F935}\x{1F470}\x{1F930}\x{1F931}\x{1F47C}\x{1F385}\x{1F936}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F483}\x{1F57A}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F6C0}\x{1F6CC}\x{1F574}\x{1F3C7}\x{1F3C2}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}\x{1F933}\x{1F4AA}\x{1F9B5}\x{1F9B6}\x{1F448}\x{1F449}\x{261D}\x{1F446}\x{1F595}\x{1F447}\x{270C}\x{1F91E}\x{1F596}\x{1F918}\x{1F919}\x{1F590}\x{270B}\x{1F44C}\x{1F44D}\x{1F44E}\x{270A}\x{1F44A}\x{1F91B}\x{1F91C}\x{1F91A}\x{1F44B}\x{1F91F}\x{270D}\x{1F44F}\x{1F450}\x{1F64C}\x{1F932}\x{1F64F}\x{1F485}\x{1F442}\x{1F443}](?:\x{1F3FE})|[\x{1F476}\x{1F9D2}\x{1F466}\x{1F467}\x{1F9D1}\x{1F468}\x{1F469}\x{1F9D3}\x{1F474}\x{1F475}\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F934}\x{1F478}\x{1F473}\x{1F472}\x{1F9D5}\x{1F9D4}\x{1F471}\x{1F935}\x{1F470}\x{1F930}\x{1F931}\x{1F47C}\x{1F385}\x{1F936}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F483}\x{1F57A}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F6C0}\x{1F6CC}\x{1F574}\x{1F3C7}\x{1F3C2}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}\x{1F933}\x{1F4AA}\x{1F9B5}\x{1F9B6}\x{1F448}\x{1F449}\x{261D}\x{1F446}\x{1F595}\x{1F447}\x{270C}\x{1F91E}\x{1F596}\x{1F918}\x{1F919}\x{1F590}\x{270B}\x{1F44C}\x{1F44D}\x{1F44E}\x{270A}\x{1F44A}\x{1F91B}\x{1F91C}\x{1F91A}\x{1F44B}\x{1F91F}\x{270D}\x{1F44F}\x{1F450}\x{1F64C}\x{1F932}\x{1F64F}\x{1F485}\x{1F442}\x{1F443}](?:\x{1F3FD})|[\x{1F476}\x{1F9D2}\x{1F466}\x{1F467}\x{1F9D1}\x{1F468}\x{1F469}\x{1F9D3}\x{1F474}\x{1F475}\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F934}\x{1F478}\x{1F473}\x{1F472}\x{1F9D5}\x{1F9D4}\x{1F471}\x{1F935}\x{1F470}\x{1F930}\x{1F931}\x{1F47C}\x{1F385}\x{1F936}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F483}\x{1F57A}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F6C0}\x{1F6CC}\x{1F574}\x{1F3C7}\x{1F3C2}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}\x{1F933}\x{1F4AA}\x{1F9B5}\x{1F9B6}\x{1F448}\x{1F449}\x{261D}\x{1F446}\x{1F595}\x{1F447}\x{270C}\x{1F91E}\x{1F596}\x{1F918}\x{1F919}\x{1F590}\x{270B}\x{1F44C}\x{1F44D}\x{1F44E}\x{270A}\x{1F44A}\x{1F91B}\x{1F91C}\x{1F91A}\x{1F44B}\x{1F91F}\x{270D}\x{1F44F}\x{1F450}\x{1F64C}\x{1F932}\x{1F64F}\x{1F485}\x{1F442}\x{1F443}](?:\x{1F3FC})|[\x{1F476}\x{1F9D2}\x{1F466}\x{1F467}\x{1F9D1}\x{1F468}\x{1F469}\x{1F9D3}\x{1F474}\x{1F475}\x{1F46E}\x{1F575}\x{1F482}\x{1F477}\x{1F934}\x{1F478}\x{1F473}\x{1F472}\x{1F9D5}\x{1F9D4}\x{1F471}\x{1F935}\x{1F470}\x{1F930}\x{1F931}\x{1F47C}\x{1F385}\x{1F936}\x{1F9D9}\x{1F9DA}\x{1F9DB}\x{1F9DC}\x{1F9DD}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F645}\x{1F646}\x{1F481}\x{1F64B}\x{1F647}\x{1F926}\x{1F937}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F6B6}\x{1F3C3}\x{1F483}\x{1F57A}\x{1F9D6}\x{1F9D7}\x{1F9D8}\x{1F6C0}\x{1F6CC}\x{1F574}\x{1F3C7}\x{1F3C2}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F3CA}\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F6B4}\x{1F6B5}\x{1F938}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F939}\x{1F933}\x{1F4AA}\x{1F9B5}\x{1F9B6}\x{1F448}\x{1F449}\x{261D}\x{1F446}\x{1F595}\x{1F447}\x{270C}\x{1F91E}\x{1F596}\x{1F918}\x{1F919}\x{1F590}\x{270B}\x{1F44C}\x{1F44D}\x{1F44E}\x{270A}\x{1F44A}\x{1F91B}\x{1F91C}\x{1F91A}\x{1F44B}\x{1F91F}\x{270D}\x{1F44F}\x{1F450}\x{1F64C}\x{1F932}\x{1F64F}\x{1F485}\x{1F442}\x{1F443}](?:\x{1F3FB})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1E9}\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FA}](?:\x{1F1FF})|[\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F1}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1FA}](?:\x{1F1FE})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F8}](?:\x{1F1FD})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F7}\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FF}](?:\x{1F1FC})|[\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1F1}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}](?:\x{1F1FB})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1ED}\x{1F1F1}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F7}\x{1F1FB}](?:\x{1F1FA})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1ED}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F1}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FE}](?:\x{1F1F9})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F1}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F7}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1FA}\x{1F1FC}](?:\x{1F1F8})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1EB}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1ED}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F1}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}](?:\x{1F1F7})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F2}](?:\x{1F1F6})|[\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1EF}\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F3}](?:\x{1F1F5})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1E9}\x{1F1EB}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1EF}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F7}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}](?:\x{1F1F4})|[\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1ED}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FA}\x{1F1FB}](?:\x{1F1F3})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1E9}\x{1F1EB}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1ED}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1EF}\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F4}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FA}\x{1F1FF}](?:\x{1F1F2})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}](?:\x{1F1F1})|[\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1E9}\x{1F1EB}\x{1F1ED}\x{1F1F1}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FD}](?:\x{1F1F0})|[\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E9}\x{1F1EB}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}](?:\x{1F1EF})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EB}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F1}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1FB}](?:\x{1F1EE})|[\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}](?:\x{1F1ED})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1E9}\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FA}\x{1F1FB}](?:\x{1F1EC})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FC}](?:\x{1F1EB})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E9}\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1EF}\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F7}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1FB}\x{1F1FE}](?:\x{1F1EA})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}](?:\x{1F1E9})|[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F1}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FB}](?:\x{1F1E8})|[\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1F1}\x{1F1F8}](?:\x{1F1E7})|[\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1F1}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F6}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FA}\x{1F1FB}\x{1F1FF}](?:\x{1F1E6})|[\x{00A9}\x{00AE}\x{203C}\x{2049}\x{2122}\x{2139}\x{2194}-\x{2199}\x{21A9}-\x{21AA}\x{231A}-\x{231B}\x{2328}\x{23CF}\x{23E9}-\x{23F3}\x{23F8}-\x{23FA}\x{24C2}\x{25AA}-\x{25AB}\x{25B6}\x{25C0}\x{25FB}-\x{25FE}\x{2600}-\x{2604}\x{260E}\x{2611}\x{2614}-\x{2615}\x{2618}\x{261D}\x{2620}\x{2622}-\x{2623}\x{2626}\x{262A}\x{262E}-\x{262F}\x{2638}-\x{263A}\x{2640}\x{2642}\x{2648}-\x{2653}\x{2660}\x{2663}\x{2665}-\x{2666}\x{2668}\x{267B}\x{267E}-\x{267F}\x{2692}-\x{2697}\x{2699}\x{269B}-\x{269C}\x{26A0}-\x{26A1}\x{26AA}-\x{26AB}\x{26B0}-\x{26B1}\x{26BD}-\x{26BE}\x{26C4}-\x{26C5}\x{26C8}\x{26CE}-\x{26CF}\x{26D1}\x{26D3}-\x{26D4}\x{26E9}-\x{26EA}\x{26F0}-\x{26F5}\x{26F7}-\x{26FA}\x{26FD}\x{2702}\x{2705}\x{2708}-\x{270D}\x{270F}\x{2712}\x{2714}\x{2716}\x{271D}\x{2721}\x{2728}\x{2733}-\x{2734}\x{2744}\x{2747}\x{274C}\x{274E}\x{2753}-\x{2755}\x{2757}\x{2763}-\x{2764}\x{2795}-\x{2797}\x{27A1}\x{27B0}\x{27BF}\x{2934}-\x{2935}\x{2B05}-\x{2B07}\x{2B1B}-\x{2B1C}\x{2B50}\x{2B55}\x{3030}\x{303D}\x{3297}\x{3299}\x{1F004}\x{1F0CF}\x{1F170}-\x{1F171}\x{1F17E}-\x{1F17F}\x{1F18E}\x{1F191}-\x{1F19A}\x{1F201}-\x{1F202}\x{1F21A}\x{1F22F}\x{1F232}-\x{1F23A}\x{1F250}-\x{1F251}\x{1F300}-\x{1F321}\x{1F324}-\x{1F393}\x{1F396}-\x{1F397}\x{1F399}-\x{1F39B}\x{1F39E}-\x{1F3F0}\x{1F3F3}-\x{1F3F5}\x{1F3F7}-\x{1F3FA}\x{1F400}-\x{1F4FD}\x{1F4FF}-\x{1F53D}\x{1F549}-\x{1F54E}\x{1F550}-\x{1F567}\x{1F56F}-\x{1F570}\x{1F573}-\x{1F57A}\x{1F587}\x{1F58A}-\x{1F58D}\x{1F590}\x{1F595}-\x{1F596}\x{1F5A4}-\x{1F5A5}\x{1F5A8}\x{1F5B1}-\x{1F5B2}\x{1F5BC}\x{1F5C2}-\x{1F5C4}\x{1F5D1}-\x{1F5D3}\x{1F5DC}-\x{1F5DE}\x{1F5E1}\x{1F5E3}\x{1F5E8}\x{1F5EF}\x{1F5F3}\x{1F5FA}-\x{1F64F}\x{1F680}-\x{1F6C5}\x{1F6CB}-\x{1F6D2}\x{1F6E0}-\x{1F6E5}\x{1F6E9}\x{1F6EB}-\x{1F6EC}\x{1F6F0}\x{1F6F3}-\x{1F6F9}\x{1F910}-\x{1F93A}\x{1F93C}-\x{1F93E}\x{1F940}-\x{1F945}\x{1F947}-\x{1F970}\x{1F973}-\x{1F976}\x{1F97A}\x{1F97C}-\x{1F9A2}\x{1F9B0}-\x{1F9B9}\x{1F9C0}-\x{1F9C2}\x{1F9D0}-\x{1F9FF}]/u', '', $text);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all emoji from string - php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35961245/how-to-remove-all-emoji-from-string-php)

Comment: if my below answer will help u then accept it.

Comment: @NalinNishant inspired by your code, I used just `preg_replace('/[[:^print:]]/', '',$string)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/12807176/1066234

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I used this function, customized with additional Unicode ranges (including more emojis and country flags), You can do the same using the details on this page http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html.

Here is the result:

```
function remove_emoji($string)
{
    // Match Enclosed Alphanumeric Supplement
    $regex_alphanumeric = '/[\x{1F100}-\x{1F1FF}]/u';
    $clear_string = preg_replace($regex_alphanumeric, '', $string);

    // Match Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs
    $regex_symbols = '/[\x{1F300}-\x{1F5FF}]/u';
    $clear_string = preg_replace($regex_symbols, '', $clear_string);

    // Match Emoticons
    $regex_emoticons = '/[\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F}]/u';
    $clear_string = preg_replace($regex_emoticons, '', $clear_string);

    // Match Transport And Map Symbols
    $regex_transport = '/[\x{1F680}-\x{1F6FF}]/u';
    $clear_string = preg_replace($regex_transport, '', $clear_string);
    
    // Match Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs
    $regex_supplemental = '/[\x{1F900}-\x{1F9FF}]/u';
    $clear_string = preg_replace($regex_supplemental, '', $clear_string);

    // Match Miscellaneous Symbols
    $regex_misc = '/[\x{2600}-\x{26FF}]/u';
    $clear_string = preg_replace($regex_misc, '', $clear_string);

    // Match Dingbats
    $regex_dingbats = '/[\x{2700}-\x{27BF}]/u';
    $clear_string = preg_replace($regex_dingbats, '', $clear_string);

    return $clear_string;
}
```

Comment: this left behind a `%` when replacing smily.

Comment: This did not remove these emojis for me  ❤️‍

Answer (score 22):

Unicode v14.0.0 and 13.00

```
  function remove_emoji($text){
    return preg_replace('/\x{1F3F4}\x{E0067}\x{E0062}(?:\x{E0077}\x{E006C}\x{E0073}|\x{E0073}\x{E0063}\x{E0074}|\x{E0065}\x{E006E}\x{E0067})\x{E007F}|(?:\x{1F9D1}\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{2764}(?:\x{FE0F}\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D})?|\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D})?)\x{1F9D1}|\x{1F469}\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1F91D}\x{200D}[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}]|\x{1FAF1}\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}\x{1FAF2})[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FE}]|(?:\x{1F9D1}\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{2764}(?:\x{FE0F}\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D})?|\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D})?)\x{1F9D1}|\x{1F469}\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1F91D}\x{200D}[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}]|\x{1FAF1}\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}\x{1FAF2})[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FD}\x{1F3FF}]|(?:\x{1F9D1}\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{2764}(?:\x{FE0F}\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D})?|\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D})?)\x{1F9D1}|\x{1F469}\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1F91D}\x{200D}[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}]|\x{1FAF1}\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}\x{1FAF2})[\x{1F3FB}\x{1F3FC}\x{1F3FE}\x{1F3FF}]|(?:\x{1F9D1}\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{2764}(?:\x{FE0F}\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D})?|\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D})?)\x{1F9D1}|\x{1F469}\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1F91D}\x{200D}[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}]|\x{1FAF1}\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}\x{1FAF2})[\x{1F3FB}\x{1F3FD}-\x{1F3FF}]|(?:\x{1F9D1}\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{2764}(?:\x{FE0F}\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D})?|\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D})?)\x{1F9D1}|\x{1F469}\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1F91D}\x{200D}[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}]|\x{1FAF1}\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{1FAF2})[\x{1F3FC}-\x{1F3FF}]|\x{1F468}(?:\x{1F3FB}(?:\x{200D}(?:\x{2764}(?:\x{FE0F}\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D}\x{1F468}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]|\x{1F468}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}])|\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D}\x{1F468}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]|\x{1F468}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]))|\x{1F91D}\x{200D}\x{1F468}[\x{1F3FC}-\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]\x{FE0F}|[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]|[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}]))?|[\x{1F3FC}-\x{1F3FF}]\x{200D}\x{2764}(?:\x{FE0F}\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D}\x{1F468}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]|\x{1F468}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}])|\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D}\x{1F468}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]|\x{1F468}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]))|\x{200D}(?:\x{2764}(?:\x{FE0F}\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D})?|\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D})?)\x{1F468}|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}]\x{200D}(?:\x{1F466}\x{200D}\x{1F466}|\x{1F467}\x{200D}[\x{1F466}\x{1F467}])|\x{1F466}\x{200D}\x{1F466}|\x{1F467}\x{200D}[\x{1F466}\x{1F467}]|[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}])|\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}(?:\x{1F91D}\x{200D}\x{1F468}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FE}]|[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}])|\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}(?:\x{1F91D}\x{200D}\x{1F468}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FD}\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}])|\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}(?:\x{1F91D}\x{200D}\x{1F468}[\x{1F3FB}\x{1F3FC}\x{1F3FE}\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}])|\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}(?:\x{1F91D}\x{200D}\x{1F468}[\x{1F3FB}\x{1F3FD}-\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}])|(?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]|\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]|\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]|\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]|\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}])\x{FE0F}|\x{200D}(?:[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}]\x{200D}[\x{1F466}\x{1F467}]|[\x{1F466}\x{1F467}])|\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]|\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]|\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]|\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]|\x{1F3FF}|\x{1F3FE}|\x{1F3FD}|\x{1F3FC}|\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}])?|(?:\x{1F469}(?:\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}\x{2764}(?:\x{FE0F}\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D}[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}]|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}])|\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D}[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}]|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}]))|[\x{1F3FC}-\x{1F3FF}]\x{200D}\x{2764}(?:\x{FE0F}\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D}[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}]|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}])|\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D}[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}]|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}])))|\x{1F9D1}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]\x{200D}\x{1F91D}\x{200D}\x{1F9D1})[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]|\x{1F469}\x{200D}\x{1F469}\x{200D}(?:\x{1F466}\x{200D}\x{1F466}|\x{1F467}\x{200D}[\x{1F466}\x{1F467}])|\x{1F469}(?:\x{200D}(?:\x{2764}(?:\x{FE0F}\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D}[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}]|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}])|\x{200D}(?:\x{1F48B}\x{200D}[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}]|[\x{1F468}\x{1F469}]))|[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}])|\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}]|\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}]|\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}]|\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}]|\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}])|\x{1F9D1}(?:\x{200D}(?:\x{1F91D}\x{200D}\x{1F9D1}|[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F384}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}])|\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F384}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}]|\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F384}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}]|\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F384}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}]|\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F384}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}]|\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}[\x{1F33E}\x{1F373}\x{1F37C}\x{1F384}\x{1F393}\x{1F3A4}\x{1F3A8}\x{1F3EB}\x{1F3ED}\x{1F4BB}\x{1F4BC}\x{1F527}\x{1F52C}\x{1F680}\x{1F692}\x{1F9AF}-\x{1F9B3}\x{1F9BC}\x{1F9BD}])|\x{1F469}\x{200D}\x{1F466}\x{200D}\x{1F466}|\x{1F469}\x{200D}\x{1F469}\x{200D}[\x{1F466}\x{1F467}]|\x{1F469}\x{200D}\x{1F467}\x{200D}[\x{1F466}\x{1F467}]|(?:\x{1F441}\x{FE0F}?\x{200D}\x{1F5E8}|\x{1F9D1}(?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]|\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]|\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]|\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]|\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]|\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}])|\x{1F469}(?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]|\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]|\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]|\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]|\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]|\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}])|\x{1F636}\x{200D}\x{1F32B}|\x{1F3F3}\x{FE0F}?\x{200D}\x{26A7}|\x{1F43B}\x{200D}\x{2744}|(?:[\x{1F3C3}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F3CA}\x{1F46E}\x{1F470}\x{1F471}\x{1F473}\x{1F477}\x{1F481}\x{1F482}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F645}-\x{1F647}\x{1F64B}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F6B4}-\x{1F6B6}\x{1F926}\x{1F935}\x{1F937}-\x{1F939}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F9B8}\x{1F9B9}\x{1F9CD}-\x{1F9CF}\x{1F9D4}\x{1F9D6}-\x{1F9DD}][\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{1F46F}\x{1F9DE}\x{1F9DF}])\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]|[\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F575}](?:[\x{FE0F}\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]|\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}])|\x{1F3F4}\x{200D}\x{2620}|[\x{1F3C3}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F3CA}\x{1F46E}\x{1F470}\x{1F471}\x{1F473}\x{1F477}\x{1F481}\x{1F482}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F645}-\x{1F647}\x{1F64B}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F6B4}-\x{1F6B6}\x{1F926}\x{1F935}\x{1F937}-\x{1F939}\x{1F93C}-\x{1F93E}\x{1F9B8}\x{1F9B9}\x{1F9CD}-\x{1F9CF}\x{1F9D4}\x{1F9D6}-\x{1F9DD}]\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]|[\xA9\xAE\x{203C}\x{2049}\x{2122}\x{2139}\x{2194}-\x{2199}\x{21A9}\x{21AA}\x{231A}\x{231B}\x{2328}\x{23CF}\x{23ED}-\x{23EF}\x{23F1}\x{23F2}\x{23F8}-\x{23FA}\x{24C2}\x{25AA}\x{25AB}\x{25B6}\x{25C0}\x{25FB}\x{25FC}\x{25FE}\x{2600}-\x{2604}\x{260E}\x{2611}\x{2614}\x{2615}\x{2618}\x{2620}\x{2622}\x{2623}\x{2626}\x{262A}\x{262E}\x{262F}\x{2638}-\x{263A}\x{2640}\x{2642}\x{2648}-\x{2653}\x{265F}\x{2660}\x{2663}\x{2665}\x{2666}\x{2668}\x{267B}\x{267E}\x{267F}\x{2692}\x{2694}-\x{2697}\x{2699}\x{269B}\x{269C}\x{26A0}\x{26A7}\x{26AA}\x{26B0}\x{26B1}\x{26BD}\x{26BE}\x{26C4}\x{26C8}\x{26CF}\x{26D1}\x{26D3}\x{26E9}\x{26F0}-\x{26F5}\x{26F7}\x{26F8}\x{26FA}\x{2702}\x{2708}\x{2709}\x{270F}\x{2712}\x{2714}\x{2716}\x{271D}\x{2721}\x{2733}\x{2734}\x{2744}\x{2747}\x{2763}\x{27A1}\x{2934}\x{2935}\x{2B05}-\x{2B07}\x{2B1B}\x{2B1C}\x{2B55}\x{3030}\x{303D}\x{3297}\x{3299}\x{1F004}\x{1F170}\x{1F171}\x{1F17E}\x{1F17F}\x{1F202}\x{1F237}\x{1F321}\x{1F324}-\x{1F32C}\x{1F336}\x{1F37D}\x{1F396}\x{1F397}\x{1F399}-\x{1F39B}\x{1F39E}\x{1F39F}\x{1F3CD}\x{1F3CE}\x{1F3D4}-\x{1F3DF}\x{1F3F5}\x{1F3F7}\x{1F43F}\x{1F4FD}\x{1F549}\x{1F54A}\x{1F56F}\x{1F570}\x{1F573}\x{1F576}-\x{1F579}\x{1F587}\x{1F58A}-\x{1F58D}\x{1F5A5}\x{1F5A8}\x{1F5B1}\x{1F5B2}\x{1F5BC}\x{1F5C2}-\x{1F5C4}\x{1F5D1}-\x{1F5D3}\x{1F5DC}-\x{1F5DE}\x{1F5E1}\x{1F5E3}\x{1F5E8}\x{1F5EF}\x{1F5F3}\x{1F5FA}\x{1F6CB}\x{1F6CD}-\x{1F6CF}\x{1F6E0}-\x{1F6E5}\x{1F6E9}\x{1F6F0}\x{1F6F3}])\x{FE0F}|\x{1F441}\x{FE0F}?\x{200D}\x{1F5E8}|\x{1F9D1}(?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]|\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]|\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]|\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]|\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]|\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}])|\x{1F469}(?:\x{1F3FF}\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]|\x{1F3FE}\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]|\x{1F3FD}\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]|\x{1F3FC}\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]|\x{1F3FB}\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}]|\x{200D}[\x{2695}\x{2696}\x{2708}])|\x{1F3F3}\x{FE0F}?\x{200D}\x{1F308}|\x{1F469}\x{200D}\x{1F467}|\x{1F469}\x{200D}\x{1F466}|\x{1F636}\x{200D}\x{1F32B}|\x{1F3F3}\x{FE0F}?\x{200D}\x{26A7}|\x{1F635}\x{200D}\x{1F4AB}|\x{1F62E}\x{200D}\x{1F4A8}|\x{1F415}\x{200D}\x{1F9BA}|\x{1FAF1}(?:\x{1F3FF}|\x{1F3FE}|\x{1F3FD}|\x{1F3FC}|\x{1F3FB})?|\x{1F9D1}(?:\x{1F3FF}|\x{1F3FE}|\x{1F3FD}|\x{1F3FC}|\x{1F3FB})?|\x{1F469}(?:\x{1F3FF}|\x{1F3FE}|\x{1F3FD}|\x{1F3FC}|\x{1F3FB})?|\x{1F43B}\x{200D}\x{2744}|(?:[\x{1F3C3}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F3CA}\x{1F46E}\x{1F470}\x{1F471}\x{1F473}\x{1F477}\x{1F481}\x{1F482}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F645}-\x{1F647}\x{1F64B}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F6B4}-\x{1F6B6}\x{1F926}\x{1F935}\x{1F937}-\x{1F939}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F9B8}\x{1F9B9}\x{1F9CD}-\x{1F9CF}\x{1F9D4}\x{1F9D6}-\x{1F9DD}][\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{1F46F}\x{1F9DE}\x{1F9DF}])\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]|[\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F575}](?:[\x{FE0F}\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]|\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}])|\x{1F3F4}\x{200D}\x{2620}|\x{1F1FD}\x{1F1F0}|\x{1F1F6}\x{1F1E6}|\x{1F1F4}\x{1F1F2}|\x{1F408}\x{200D}\x{2B1B}|\x{2764}(?:\x{FE0F}\x{200D}[\x{1F525}\x{1FA79}]|\x{200D}[\x{1F525}\x{1FA79}])|\x{1F441}\x{FE0F}?|\x{1F3F3}\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F3C3}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F3CA}\x{1F46E}\x{1F470}\x{1F471}\x{1F473}\x{1F477}\x{1F481}\x{1F482}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F645}-\x{1F647}\x{1F64B}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F6B4}-\x{1F6B6}\x{1F926}\x{1F935}\x{1F937}-\x{1F939}\x{1F93C}-\x{1F93E}\x{1F9B8}\x{1F9B9}\x{1F9CD}-\x{1F9CF}\x{1F9D4}\x{1F9D6}-\x{1F9DD}]\x{200D}[\x{2640}\x{2642}]|\x{1F1FF}[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1FC}]|\x{1F1FE}[\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1F9}]|\x{1F1FC}[\x{1F1EB}\x{1F1F8}]|\x{1F1FB}[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1FA}]|\x{1F1FA}[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1FE}\x{1F1FF}]|\x{1F1F9}[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1E9}\x{1F1EB}-\x{1F1ED}\x{1F1EF}-\x{1F1F4}\x{1F1F7}\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FB}\x{1F1FC}\x{1F1FF}]|\x{1F1F8}[\x{1F1E6}-\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1EC}-\x{1F1F4}\x{1F1F7}-\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FB}\x{1F1FD}-\x{1F1FF}]|\x{1F1F7}[\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1F4}\x{1F1F8}\x{1F1FA}\x{1F1FC}]|\x{1F1F5}[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1EA}-\x{1F1ED}\x{1F1F0}-\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F7}-\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FC}\x{1F1FE}]|\x{1F1F3}[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EA}-\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F1}\x{1F1F4}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F7}\x{1F1FA}\x{1F1FF}]|\x{1F1F2}[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E8}-\x{1F1ED}\x{1F1F0}-\x{1F1FF}]|\x{1F1F1}[\x{1F1E6}-\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F7}-\x{1F1FB}\x{1F1FE}]|\x{1F1F0}[\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1EC}-\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F7}\x{1F1FC}\x{1F1FE}\x{1F1FF}]|\x{1F1EF}[\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F4}\x{1F1F5}]|\x{1F1EE}[\x{1F1E8}-\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1F1}-\x{1F1F4}\x{1F1F6}-\x{1F1F9}]|\x{1F1ED}[\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F7}\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FA}]|\x{1F1EC}[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E9}-\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F1}-\x{1F1F3}\x{1F1F5}-\x{1F1FA}\x{1F1FC}\x{1F1FE}]|\x{1F1EB}[\x{1F1EE}-\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F4}\x{1F1F7}]|\x{1F1EA}[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1ED}\x{1F1F7}-\x{1F1FA}]|\x{1F1E9}[\x{1F1EA}\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1EF}\x{1F1F0}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F4}\x{1F1FF}]|\x{1F1E8}[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E8}\x{1F1E9}\x{1F1EB}-\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F0}-\x{1F1F5}\x{1F1F7}\x{1F1FA}-\x{1F1FF}]|\x{1F1E7}[\x{1F1E6}\x{1F1E7}\x{1F1E9}-\x{1F1EF}\x{1F1F1}-\x{1F1F4}\x{1F1F6}-\x{1F1F9}\x{1F1FB}\x{1F1FC}\x{1F1FE}\x{1F1FF}]|\x{1F1E6}[\x{1F1E8}-\x{1F1EC}\x{1F1EE}\x{1F1F1}\x{1F1F2}\x{1F1F4}\x{1F1F6}-\x{1F1FA}\x{1F1FC}\x{1F1FD}\x{1F1FF}]|[#\*0-9]\x{FE0F}?\x{20E3}|\x{1F93C}[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]|\x{2764}\x{FE0F}?|[\x{1F3C3}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F3CA}\x{1F46E}\x{1F470}\x{1F471}\x{1F473}\x{1F477}\x{1F481}\x{1F482}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F645}-\x{1F647}\x{1F64B}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F6B4}-\x{1F6B6}\x{1F926}\x{1F935}\x{1F937}-\x{1F939}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F9B8}\x{1F9B9}\x{1F9CD}-\x{1F9CF}\x{1F9D4}\x{1F9D6}-\x{1F9DD}][\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{26F9}\x{1F3CB}\x{1F3CC}\x{1F575}][\x{FE0F}\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]?|\x{1F3F4}|[\x{270A}\x{270B}\x{1F385}\x{1F3C2}\x{1F3C7}\x{1F442}\x{1F443}\x{1F446}-\x{1F450}\x{1F466}\x{1F467}\x{1F46B}-\x{1F46D}\x{1F472}\x{1F474}-\x{1F476}\x{1F478}\x{1F47C}\x{1F483}\x{1F485}\x{1F48F}\x{1F491}\x{1F4AA}\x{1F57A}\x{1F595}\x{1F596}\x{1F64C}\x{1F64F}\x{1F6C0}\x{1F6CC}\x{1F90C}\x{1F90F}\x{1F918}-\x{1F91F}\x{1F930}-\x{1F934}\x{1F936}\x{1F977}\x{1F9B5}\x{1F9B6}\x{1F9BB}\x{1F9D2}\x{1F9D3}\x{1F9D5}\x{1FAC3}-\x{1FAC5}\x{1FAF0}\x{1FAF2}-\x{1FAF6}][\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{261D}\x{270C}\x{270D}\x{1F574}\x{1F590}][\x{FE0F}\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]|[\x{261D}\x{270A}-\x{270D}\x{1F385}\x{1F3C2}\x{1F3C7}\x{1F408}\x{1F415}\x{1F43B}\x{1F442}\x{1F443}\x{1F446}-\x{1F450}\x{1F466}\x{1F467}\x{1F46B}-\x{1F46D}\x{1F472}\x{1F474}-\x{1F476}\x{1F478}\x{1F47C}\x{1F483}\x{1F485}\x{1F48F}\x{1F491}\x{1F4AA}\x{1F574}\x{1F57A}\x{1F590}\x{1F595}\x{1F596}\x{1F62E}\x{1F635}\x{1F636}\x{1F64C}\x{1F64F}\x{1F6C0}\x{1F6CC}\x{1F90C}\x{1F90F}\x{1F918}-\x{1F91F}\x{1F930}-\x{1F934}\x{1F936}\x{1F93C}\x{1F977}\x{1F9B5}\x{1F9B6}\x{1F9BB}\x{1F9D2}\x{1F9D3}\x{1F9D5}\x{1FAC3}-\x{1FAC5}\x{1FAF0}\x{1FAF2}-\x{1FAF6}]|[\x{1F3C3}\x{1F3C4}\x{1F3CA}\x{1F46E}\x{1F470}\x{1F471}\x{1F473}\x{1F477}\x{1F481}\x{1F482}\x{1F486}\x{1F487}\x{1F645}-\x{1F647}\x{1F64B}\x{1F64D}\x{1F64E}\x{1F6A3}\x{1F6B4}-\x{1F6B6}\x{1F926}\x{1F935}\x{1F937}-\x{1F939}\x{1F93D}\x{1F93E}\x{1F9B8}\x{1F9B9}\x{1F9CD}-\x{1F9CF}\x{1F9D4}\x{1F9D6}-\x{1F9DD}]|[\x{1F46F}\x{1F9DE}\x{1F9DF}]|[\xA9\xAE\x{203C}\x{2049}\x{2122}\x{2139}\x{2194}-\x{2199}\x{21A9}\x{21AA}\x{231A}\x{231B}\x{2328}\x{23CF}\x{23ED}-\x{23EF}\x{23F1}\x{23F2}\x{23F8}-\x{23FA}\x{24C2}\x{25AA}\x{25AB}\x{25B6}\x{25C0}\x{25FB}\x{25FC}\x{25FE}\x{2600}-\x{2604}\x{260E}\x{2611}\x{2614}\x{2615}\x{2618}\x{2620}\x{2622}\x{2623}\x{2626}\x{262A}\x{262E}\x{262F}\x{2638}-\x{263A}\x{2640}\x{2642}\x{2648}-\x{2653}\x{265F}\x{2660}\x{2663}\x{2665}\x{2666}\x{2668}\x{267B}\x{267E}\x{267F}\x{2692}\x{2694}-\x{2697}\x{2699}\x{269B}\x{269C}\x{26A0}\x{26A7}\x{26AA}\x{26B0}\x{26B1}\x{26BD}\x{26BE}\x{26C4}\x{26C8}\x{26CF}\x{26D1}\x{26D3}\x{26E9}\x{26F0}-\x{26F5}\x{26F7}\x{26F8}\x{26FA}\x{2702}\x{2708}\x{2709}\x{270F}\x{2712}\x{2714}\x{2716}\x{271D}\x{2721}\x{2733}\x{2734}\x{2744}\x{2747}\x{2763}\x{27A1}\x{2934}\x{2935}\x{2B05}-\x{2B07}\x{2B1B}\x{2B1C}\x{2B55}\x{3030}\x{303D}\x{3297}\x{3299}\x{1F004}\x{1F170}\x{1F171}\x{1F17E}\x{1F17F}\x{1F202}\x{1F237}\x{1F321}\x{1F324}-\x{1F32C}\x{1F336}\x{1F37D}\x{1F396}\x{1F397}\x{1F399}-\x{1F39B}\x{1F39E}\x{1F39F}\x{1F3CD}\x{1F3CE}\x{1F3D4}-\x{1F3DF}\x{1F3F5}\x{1F3F7}\x{1F43F}\x{1F4FD}\x{1F549}\x{1F54A}\x{1F56F}\x{1F570}\x{1F573}\x{1F576}-\x{1F579}\x{1F587}\x{1F58A}-\x{1F58D}\x{1F5A5}\x{1F5A8}\x{1F5B1}\x{1F5B2}\x{1F5BC}\x{1F5C2}-\x{1F5C4}\x{1F5D1}-\x{1F5D3}\x{1F5DC}-\x{1F5DE}\x{1F5E1}\x{1F5E3}\x{1F5E8}\x{1F5EF}\x{1F5F3}\x{1F5FA}\x{1F6CB}\x{1F6CD}-\x{1F6CF}\x{1F6E0}-\x{1F6E5}\x{1F6E9}\x{1F6F0}\x{1F6F3}]|[\x{23E9}-\x{23EC}\x{23F0}\x{23F3}\x{25FD}\x{2693}\x{26A1}\x{26AB}\x{26C5}\x{26CE}\x{26D4}\x{26EA}\x{26FD}\x{2705}\x{2728}\x{274C}\x{274E}\x{2753}-\x{2755}\x{2757}\x{2795}-\x{2797}\x{27B0}\x{27BF}\x{2B50}\x{1F0CF}\x{1F18E}\x{1F191}-\x{1F19A}\x{1F201}\x{1F21A}\x{1F22F}\x{1F232}-\x{1F236}\x{1F238}-\x{1F23A}\x{1F250}\x{1F251}\x{1F300}-\x{1F320}\x{1F32D}-\x{1F335}\x{1F337}-\x{1F37C}\x{1F37E}-\x{1F384}\x{1F386}-\x{1F393}\x{1F3A0}-\x{1F3C1}\x{1F3C5}\x{1F3C6}\x{1F3C8}\x{1F3C9}\x{1F3CF}-\x{1F3D3}\x{1F3E0}-\x{1F3F0}\x{1F3F8}-\x{1F407}\x{1F409}-\x{1F414}\x{1F416}-\x{1F43A}\x{1F43C}-\x{1F43E}\x{1F440}\x{1F444}\x{1F445}\x{1F451}-\x{1F465}\x{1F46A}\x{1F479}-\x{1F47B}\x{1F47D}-\x{1F480}\x{1F484}\x{1F488}-\x{1F48E}\x{1F490}\x{1F492}-\x{1F4A9}\x{1F4AB}-\x{1F4FC}\x{1F4FF}-\x{1F53D}\x{1F54B}-\x{1F54E}\x{1F550}-\x{1F567}\x{1F5A4}\x{1F5FB}-\x{1F62D}\x{1F62F}-\x{1F634}\x{1F637}-\x{1F644}\x{1F648}-\x{1F64A}\x{1F680}-\x{1F6A2}\x{1F6A4}-\x{1F6B3}\x{1F6B7}-\x{1F6BF}\x{1F6C1}-\x{1F6C5}\x{1F6D0}-\x{1F6D2}\x{1F6D5}-\x{1F6D7}\x{1F6DD}-\x{1F6DF}\x{1F6EB}\x{1F6EC}\x{1F6F4}-\x{1F6FC}\x{1F7E0}-\x{1F7EB}\x{1F7F0}\x{1F90D}\x{1F90E}\x{1F910}-\x{1F917}\x{1F920}-\x{1F925}\x{1F927}-\x{1F92F}\x{1F93A}\x{1F93F}-\x{1F945}\x{1F947}-\x{1F976}\x{1F978}-\x{1F9B4}\x{1F9B7}\x{1F9BA}\x{1F9BC}-\x{1F9CC}\x{1F9D0}\x{1F9E0}-\x{1F9FF}\x{1FA70}-\x{1FA74}\x{1FA78}-\x{1FA7C}\x{1FA80}-\x{1FA86}\x{1FA90}-\x{1FAAC}\x{1FAB0}-\x{1FABA}\x{1FAC0}-\x{1FAC2}\x{1FAD0}-\x{1FAD9}\x{1FAE0}-\x{1FAE7}]/u', '', $text);
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution since strlen gives the right value after using it

Comment: This answer is more complete than the official one from ceyquem. Thank you, it removes all emojis and symbols for me.

Comment: Works! Tested in different scenarios! Thanks for this.

Comment: unbelievable, the only solution that actually works and removes all emojis...

Answer (score 10):

Here is my code that I am currently using in my project to remove all emojis from a string.

```
function remove_emoji($string) {

    // Match Emoticons
    $regex_emoticons = '/[\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F}]/u';
    $clear_string = preg_replace($regex_emoticons, '', $string);

    // Match Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs
    $regex_symbols = '/[\x{1F300}-\x{1F5FF}]/u';
    $clear_string = preg_replace($regex_symbols, '', $clear_string);

    // Match Transport And Map Symbols
    $regex_transport = '/[\x{1F680}-\x{1F6FF}]/u';
    $clear_string = preg_replace($regex_transport, '', $clear_string);

    // Match Miscellaneous Symbols
    $regex_misc = '/[\x{2600}-\x{26FF}]/u';
    $clear_string = preg_replace($regex_misc, '', $clear_string);

    // Match Dingbats
    $regex_dingbats = '/[\x{2700}-\x{27BF}]/u';
    $clear_string = preg_replace($regex_dingbats, '', $clear_string);

    return $clear_string;
}
```

Comment: it does not catch all emojis. for example: ; help?

Comment: @dor you can extend it with additional ranges: http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html - for instance flags are /[\x{1F100}-\x{1F1FF}]/u and supplemental symbols are /[\x{1F900}-\x{1F9FF}]/u

Comment: its work good thx

Comment: How about variant selectors, for example red heart on apple devices contains two unicode symbols `&#x2764;&#xFE0F;` https://regex101.com/r/TSYYgf/1. Here about variant selectors https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFE00.pdf

Answer (score 8):

Shorter function based on previous answers.

```
function remove_emoji($string) {
    $symbols = "\x{1F100}-\x{1F1FF}" // Enclosed Alphanumeric Supplement
        ."\x{1F300}-\x{1F5FF}" // Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs
        ."\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F}" //Emoticons
        ."\x{1F680}-\x{1F6FF}" // Transport And Map Symbols
        ."\x{1F900}-\x{1F9FF}" // Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs
        ."\x{2600}-\x{26FF}" // Miscellaneous Symbols
        ."\x{2700}-\x{27BF}"; // Dingbats

    return preg_replace('/['. $symbols . ']+/u', '', $string);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Small update for Nalin answer

We need to match emoji with variant selectors too, for example:

- ❤️ matches two unicode symbols pair `\x{2764}\x{FE0F}`
- matches two unicode symbols pair `\x{1F44D}\x{1F3FF}`

```php
function remove_emoji(string $string): string
{

    /**
     * @see https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFE00.pdf
     */
    $variant_selectors = '[\x{FE00}–\x{FE0F}]?'; // ? - optional

    /**
     * There are many sets of modifiers
     * such as skin color modifiers and etc
     *
     * Not used, because this range already included
     * in 'Match Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs' range
     * $skin_modifiers = '[\x{1F3FB}-\x{1F3FF}]';
     *
     * Full list of modifiers:
     * https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-modifiers.html
     */

    // Match Enclosed Alphanumeric Supplement
    $regex_alphanumeric = "/[\x{1F100}-\x{1F1FF}]$variant_selectors/u";
    $clear_string = preg_replace($regex_alphanumeric, '', $string);

    // Match Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs
    $regex_symbols = "/[\x{1F300}-\x{1F5FF}]$variant_selectors/u";
    $clear_string = preg_replace($regex_symbols, '', $clear_string);

    // Match Emoticons
    $regex_emoticons = "/[\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F}]$variant_selectors/u";
    $clear_string = preg_replace($regex_emoticons, '', $clear_string);

    // Match Transport And Map Symbols
    $regex_transport = "/[\x{1F680}-\x{1F6FF}]$variant_selectors/u";
    $clear_string = preg_replace($regex_transport, '', $clear_string);

    // Match Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs
    $regex_supplemental = "/[\x{1F900}-\x{1F9FF}]$variant_selectors/u";
    $clear_string = preg_replace($regex_supplemental, '', $clear_string);

    // Match Miscellaneous Symbols
    $regex_misc = "/[\x{2600}-\x{26FF}]$variant_selectors/u";
    $clear_string = preg_replace($regex_misc, '', $clear_string);

    // Match Dingbats
    $regex_dingbats = "/[\x{2700}-\x{27BF}]$variant_selectors/u";
    $clear_string = preg_replace($regex_dingbats, '', $clear_string);

    return $clear_string;
}
```

Comment: this one is best since it works with two unicode symbols and removes strange chars

Answer (score 2):

Works to me:

```
function removeEmoji($text)
{
    return preg_replace('/([\x{0001F000}-\x{0001FAFF}])/mu', '', $text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets Try work like charm!

```
function remove_emoji($str)
{
    $str = preg_replace_callback(
        '/./u',
        function (array $match) {
            return strlen($match[0]) >= 4 ? '' : $match[0];
        },
        $str
    );
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: No ♂️‍♀️️‍⚧️‍☠️