# Strip emojis from UTF8 string (mb4)

Tags: php, regex, unicode, emoji

I'm looking for a method to strip/remove all emojis from a UTF8 string. I have found a few solutions but none of them seems bullet proof

https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/index.html

I came across this post [Remove emojis from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61481567/remove-emojis-from-string) which recommend this method, but a few comments tell it doesn't catch everything

```
function remove_emoji($string) {
    $symbols = "\x{1F100}-\x{1F1FF}" // Enclosed Alphanumeric Supplement
        ."\x{1F300}-\x{1F5FF}" // Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs
        ."\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F}" //Emoticons
        ."\x{1F680}-\x{1F6FF}" // Transport And Map Symbols
        ."\x{1F900}-\x{1F9FF}" // Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs
        ."\x{2600}-\x{26FF}" // Miscellaneous Symbols
        ."\x{2700}-\x{27BF}"; // Dingbats

    return preg_replace('/['. $symbols . ']+/u', '', $string);
}
```

I also found this method which seems more sophisticated

```
function strip_mb4(string $str): string{
    $planes_1_3     = '\xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2}';
    $planes_4_15    = '[\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3}';
    $plane_16       = '\xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2}';
    
    return preg_replace("/(?:$planes_1_3|$planes_4_15|$plane_16)/", '', $str);
}
```

I haven't fully tested the two methods. Can anyone tell me which one would catch most or even all emojis, or do you have an even better method to use?

Comment: This seems to be an exact duplicate of the question you already found. If you want to attract new answers, maybe you could [set a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on it.

Comment: @IMSoP but the accepted answer is not working 100%.. Thats why I created a new question.....

Comment: @IMSoP the accepted answer should not have been accepted!

Comment: If someone answered *this* question, the other one *still* wouldn't have a correct answer. That's why I suggested a bounty - to attract new answers without splitting then across multiple identical questions.

Comment: How do you want me to make a good explanation when it's not my question?

Comment: When you create a bounty, you can add a description of why. Given that the question has already been asked at least three times, with a number of answers along the same lines, just asking again doesn't seem likely to get anywhere.