# preg_replace keep alphanumeric + Latin + emojis

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to filter out all, but alphanumeric, Latin-Chars AND emojis

```
$str="Hello José' [](){}✅., welcome";
```

wanted result:

Hello José ✅ welcome

```
echo preg_replace("/[^\p{Latin} \wp-]/u",'',$str); // this is what i need
```

but i also need to keep the emojis ✅

I have 2 , but one deletes also the emojis, the other keep emojis but deletes everything else.
i need this 2 combined

```
preg_replace("/[^\p{Latin} \wp-]/u",'',$str);

preg_replace("/[ -\x{2122}]\s+|\s*[ -\x{2122}]/u",'',$str);
```

Comment: Does `preg_replace("/(?!-)\p{P}/u",'',$str)` work well enough for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace("/[^\p{Latin} \x{200d}\x{2600}-\x{1FAFF}0-9]/u",'',$str)
```

The area \x{2600}-\x{1F6FF} still contains some characters that are not emojis. Details see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807176/php-writing-a-simple-removeemoji-function). possibly specify several areas. I've included the digits 0-9.

Comment: some emojis (maybe new ones) were excluded but by setting the end range to 1FAFF they are all included

`preg_replace("/[^\p{Latin} \x{2600}-\x{1FAFF}0-9+]/u",'',$str);`

Comment: maybe a little off topic but
'$str="️‍";

echo "️‍";
echo "<br>";
echo $str;
echo preg_replace("/[^\p{Latin} \x{2600}-\x{1FAFF}0-9+]/u",'',$str);'

before preg_replace it stays 1 emoji

while after preg_replace they become 2 emojis
is there a way to prevent that.

Comment: Wiktor Stribizew your code  doesn't strip html mark-up like .
what i really need is alphanumeric +Latin chars + emojis. nothing else
jspit answer does all that, only with a slight problem with combination emojis.
like "rainbowflag" becomes "flag" + "Rainbow".

For the rest his code works fine

Comment: @david Very well, but you should know there is no way to match all emojis correctly in PHP regex, because it has a pattern limit, and a regex to match emojis correctly is very long. You should try to come up with a reverse logic if possible, else live with a good-enough workaround.

Comment: I've edited my post. Does this solve the problem with the combination emojis?
Wiktor is right in principle with his comment.
His approach can easily be expanded with the characters that should still be removed: preg_replace("/(?!-)[\p{P}<>$]/u",'',$str)