# CKeditor restrict emoticons in touch devices

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using inline CKEditor. I have removed the emoticons options from toolbar. But I can still insert emoticons from the IPAD keyboard.

Any idea on how I can restrict/filter the emoticons in ckeditor in touch devices.

Thanks.

Comment: real time javascript validation. listen on keypress or text area value change and validate accordingly.

Comment: I tried that. I used this regex /([\uE000-\uF8FF]|\uD83C[\uDF00-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDDFF])/g
But it doesnot cover all the emoticons available in ipad.

Comment: then why not drop that regex, and just hard-code all the emoticons available in the ipad in your matching function?

Comment: Isn't anything possible from ckeditor filter plugin, or config. Ipad emoticons cannot be easily covered by regex. check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992921/how-to-remove-emoji-code-using-javascript.
And if i dont have a clean solution, at last i would go with this.