# HTML & Javascript |iOS| - Remove/Exclude emojis

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I currently have a HTML textarea tag to allow a user to input some kind text, this is fine.

The problem I have is that the user is allowed to input emojis, I would live to know if there is anyway I can remove said emojis after the user has inputted them or better yet stop the user inputting them in the first place.

Is it possible to remove the emote key on iOS keyboard for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to remove functionality from devices.

However someone has asked this question before and an answer has been given.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10999907/4053708

Hope this helps you out as well.