# How to convert string with emoji, convert emoji to string like this url with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

How to convert string with emoji ❤️, convert emoji to string like this question url `%EF%B8%8F` with regex?

```
function emojitourl(str) {

return str;
}


var str = 'Thats a  ';
console.log( emojitourl(str) ); // Thats a ??
```

Comment: Aren't the emoji in your `str` variable already unicode? Your function is not converting them to unicode, it's URL-encoding them, which is something different altogether. What exactly is it you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @torazaburo thanks for reply I wanto convert the emoji icon to code like this question url

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you want. [This page](http://crocodillon.com/blog/parsing-emoji-unicode-in-javascript) helped me to sort out the ranges for the emoji characters. Apparently emoji characters are represented by two successive UTF16 characters called surrogate pairs. As a side info, each emoji character increase the length value of a string by 2.

```js
function emojiToUnicode(s) {
return s.match(/\ud83c[\udf00-\udfff]|\ud83d[\udc00-\ude4f]|\ud83d[\ude80-\udeff]/g)
        .map( e => "\\u" + e.charCodeAt(0).toString(16) + "\\u" + e.charCodeAt(1).toString(16))
}

var str = 'Thats a  ';
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(emojiToUnicode(str), 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: thanks for reply, I user yours make https://jsfiddle.net/geqc21u0/ but theres error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'` ?

Comment: Thanks for the link reference.  the emoji represent in this question url %EF%B8%8F is "utf16" ?

Comment: @user1575921 i have checked it should be working please retry and i can not see any %EF%B8%8F in this question url.

Answer (score 0):

I realise that I'm a bit late to the party here, but as a follow on from Redu's answer, here is the updated regex to ensure you grab even more emoji's.

```
function emojiToUnicode(s) {
    return s.match(/([\u2700-\u27BF]|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\uD83C[\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\u2011-\u26FF]|\uD83E[\uDD10-\uDDFF])/g)
        .map( e => "\\u" + e.charCodeAt(0).toString(16) + "\\u" + e.charCodeAt(1).toString(16))
}
```

and I also wanted to add that if you would like to keep the original string with just the emoji's replaced with unicode, you should do something like this:

```
function emojiToUnicode(str) {
    return str.replace(/([\u2700-\u27BF]|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\uD83C[\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\u2011-\u26FF]|\uD83E[\uDD10-\uDDFF])/g, function(e) {
        return "\\u" + e.charCodeAt(0).toString(16) + "\\u" + e.charCodeAt(1).toString(16);
    });
}
```

(Credit for the updated regex search: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41543705/6756350)