# Prevent emoji and zero width characters in text input

Tags: html, regex

Is their a regex which I can use within the pattern attribute on a input tag to prevent people adding emojis and zero width spaces?

Comment: You will need to use JavaScript to achieve this. This will help you with the emojis: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992921/how-to-remove-emoji-code-using-javascript

Comment: Try `pattern="(?!.*(?:[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\uD83C[\uDF00-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDDFF])).*"`

Comment: Browser is stating that isn't a valid pattern @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Ah yes, because you must be testing in FF or Chrome, and they are already using the `/u` tag.

Comment: @PI: But you didn't mention anything related to browser restrictions in your question.

Comment: Try `pattern="(?!.*[\u{1F600}-\u{1F6FF}\u2600-\u26FF\u200B]).*"`. BTW, what emojis are you trying to disallow? All in http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts-beta/full-emoji-list.html?

Answer (score -2):

```
document.getElementById('myinput').onkeypress = function() {
    var char = String.fromCharCode(event.which);   
    if (char.match(/([\uE000-\uF8FF]|\uD83C[\uDF00-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDDFF])|\s/)) {
            event.preventDefault();
    }
};
```

See my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0juLfy4g/1/

Comment: I just tested and was able to paste an Emoji into that JSFiddle. I don't think it worked as expected.

Comment: @user1567291 This solution wouldn't work if you're pasting into a field rather than typing directly. Try replacing `onkeypress` with `onpaste`