# Remove Emoji's from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can i remove (or) hide the emoji's in android device keyboard.

Because my android application login input password field was accepted the emoji's to crash the app.

So, emoji's are not accepted input field in  jquery or javascript programatically.

Comment: Why do you not use `android` tag  ?

Comment: That's why _they_ invented input validation

Comment: This is something on the device's side, I don't think you can use javascript to disable this. Like @AlonEitan mensioned, use input validation

Comment: String.replace (/[\u{1F600}-\u{1F6FF}]/, "")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove emoji code using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992921/how-to-remove-emoji-code-using-javascript)

Comment: But how to use the code?

Comment: Else check emoji's detect in input fields condition?