# Unicode points rendering difference in a browser: HTML characters vs jQuery.html

Tags: jquery, html, browser, unicode

Let's say I have the following basic HTML page

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    \u00f2
  </body>
</html>
```

When the page renders, what I see is \u00f2 whereas I was expecting ò. And there comes the big "but". With the following Javascript code, what I see is the ò character (2 seconds later).

```
$(function(){
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    $("body").html("\u00f2")},2000);
  });
});
```

My question is, why is this happening? I am aware of rather than rendering the Unicode codepoints, I could convert them to HTML entities and render the correct character directly. The question is more for learning purposes.

Here is [the jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ubofih/1/edit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because in HTML, `\u00f2` is just a sequence of five characters; the backslash `\` never has any special meaning in HTML. In JavaScript strings, \u00f2 has a special meaning: it denotes the Unicode code unit with hexadecimal number 00f2, i.e. the chacter “ò”.

Conversely, although you can use `&#x00f2;` in HTML to denote “ò”, you cannot do that in JavaScript, though you could use functions that convert `&#x00f2;` (which is just a sequence of eight characters from the JavaScript point of view) to “ò”. Moreover, if your JavaScript code appears as embedded in HTML in a `script` element or in an event attribute, then browsers may, depending on certain rules, first interpret `&#x00f2;` by HTML rules before invoking the JavaScript interpreter.

In HTML documents, the modern, generally recommendable method is to enter the characters directly, using the UTF-8 encoding. You can do the same in JavaScript, too, e.g. `$("body").html("ò")},2000)`. However, this is sometimes avoided due to assumed or real complications in specifying the [character encoding](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset.en.php).

Answer (score 3):

This is because `\u00f2` is not valid HTML markup for unicode characters.  The proper HTML markup is `&#x00f2`.  All you need to do is replace `\u` with `&#x` and you should be fine.

If you want to know why jQuery uses `\u`, it is because javascript uses `\u` designate unicode characters.  You can read more here: [jquery .text() and unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087027/jquery-text-and-unicode).

In short, use `\u` in Javascript, `&#x` in HTML, and don't try to switch that around or you'll run into problems (such as what is happening here)

Comment: UTF-16 and UTF-32 are two transfer encodings for Unicode and should not be confused with the issue that JavaScript may support only BMP.

Comment: Updated the answer to remove reference to UTF-16