# How To Escape a PHP Variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying to create a Javascript function that echoes out a Wordpress function called the_title() which just returns the title of the a blog. Through PHP it echoes out fine but when I do it through Javscript, however, quotes seem to be unescaped (specifically single quotes). Any help or explanation why this is happening?

**THE CODE:**

```
function createSliderTabs() {   
    var para = document.createElement("li");
    var strings = "<?php the_title(); ?>";
    var post_string = strings.replace(/"/g, "").replace(/'/g, "").replace(/\(|\)/g, "");
    var node = document.createTextNode(post_string);
    para.appendChild(node);
    var element = document.getElementById("control-navigation");
    element.appendChild(para);
}

    createSliderTabs();
```

**THE RESULT:** 
Macy&#8217 ;s Herald Square (had to include space or it would've changed to single quote)

**WHAT IT SHOULD BE:** 
Macy's Herald Square

Any help or guidance on why this is happening? Thx in advance...

Comment: WordPress is printing the title with `&#8217;`. And as you use a text node which can’t contain HTML, you see `&#8217;` and not `’`, the character which `&#8217;` refers to.

Comment: Oooo....any direction on how to escape it or convert it?

Comment: Perhaps make node a span rather than a textnode, and set its innerHTML to post_string? That might not work, just throwin' out ideas.

Answer (score 2):

From php to js transformation you always have to use [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

- to avoid [xss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)
- to describe [unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793998/unicode-points-rendering-difference-in-a-browser-html-characters-vs-jquery-html)

Answer (score -1):

You can use [html_entity_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php):

I'm not really familiar with wordpress, but I suppose you would use it inside the_title():

```
function the_title()
{
   $str = 'Macy&#8217;s Herald Square';
   echo html_entity_decode ($str, ENT_COMPAT , "UTF-8");
}
```

If you need to use [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) you should be able to do

```
$json = html_entity_decode(json_encode($array), ENT_COMPAT , "UTF-8");
```

EDIT: added `ENT_COMPAT , "UTF-8"`