# How to escape a character out of Basic Multilingual Plane?

Tags: javascript, unicode, non-english, astral-plane

For characters in Basic Multilingual Plane, we can use '\uxxxx' escape it. For example, you can use /[\u4e00-\u9fff]/ to match a common chinese character(0x4e00-0x9fff is the range of CJK Unified Ideographs).

But for characters out of Basic Multilingual Plane, their codes are bigger than 0xffff. So you can't use format '\uxxxx' to escape it, because '\u20000' means character '\u2000' and character '0', not a character which code is 0x20000.

How can I escape characters out of Basic Multilingual Plane? Use those characters directly is not a good idea, because they can't show in most fonts.

Comment: @millimoose Uh, but this question is about **javascript**, not java.

Comment: Whoops, my bad. (You're probably just as screwed there though; if not more so.)

Comment: Related: [JavaScript strings outside of the BMP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744721/javascript-strings-outside-of-the-bmp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pair of escaped surrogate code points, as described in @duskwuff’s answer. You can use my [Full Unicode input utility](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/fui.html8) to get the notations (button “Show \u”), or use the Fileformat.info [character search](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm) to find them out (item “C/C++/Java source code”, because JavaScript uses the same notation here).

Alternatively, you can enter the characters directly: “You can enter non-BMP characters *as such* into string literals in your JavaScript code,whether in a separate file or as embedded in HTML. Naturally, you need suitable Unicode support in the editor you use. But JavaScript implementations need not support non-BMP characters in program source. They may, and modern browser implementations generally do.” (Going Global with JavaScript and Globalize.js, p. 177) There are some caveats like properly declaring the character encoding.

Font support is a different issue, but when working with characters, you generally want to see them at some point anyway, at least in testing. So you more or less need some font(s) that cover the characters. The Fileformat.info pages also contain links to browser support info, such as [(U+20000) Font Support](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20000/fontsupport.htm) – a good starting point, though not quite complete. For example, U+20000 `''` is also supported in SimSun-ExtB

Answer (score 2):

Characters outside the BMP are not recognized directly by Javascript -- they're represented internally as UTF-16 surrogate pairs. For instance, the character you mentioned, U+20000 (currently allocated to "CJK Unified Ideographs Ext. B") is represented as the surrogate pair U+D840 U+DC00. As a Javascript string, this would simply be `"\u2840\uDC00"`. (Note that `s.length` is 2 for this string, even though it displays as a single character.)

[Wikipedia has details on the encoding scheme used.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF)

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem.

Now that we have [ES6](http://es6-features.org/), [we can do this](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#unicode-code-point):

```
let newSpeak = '\u{1F4A9}'
```

Note that internally it's still [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) with [surrogate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF):

```
newSpeak.length === 2 // "wrong"
[...newSpeak].length === 1
newSpeak === '\uD83D\uDCA9'
```

[Unicode is huge](http://www.parseerror.com/blog/visualizing-unicode-codespace).

Also, it's not just the literals:

```
newSpeak.charCodeAt(0) === 0xD83D // "wrong"
newSpeak.codePointAt(0) === 0x1F4A9

String.fromCharCode(0x1F4A9) !== newSpeak
String.fromCodePoint(0x1F4A9) === newSpeak

for (let i = 0; i < newSpeak.length; i++) console.log(newSpeak[i]) // "wrong"
for (let c of newSpeak) console.log(c)

[...''].map(c => `__${c}`).join('') === "____"
```

I � handling Unicode.