# replace emoji unicode symbol using regexp in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, emoji

As you all know [emoji](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode#block-6b-missing-transport-and-map-symbols) symbols are coded up to 3 or 4 bytes, so it may occupy 2 symbols in my string. For example 'wew'.length = 7
I want to find those symbols in my text and replace them to the value that is dependent from its code. 
Reading SO, I came up to XRegExp library with unicode plugin, but have not found the way how to make it work.

```
var str = 'wew';// \u1F601 symbol
var reg = XRegExp('[\u1F601-\u1F64F]', 'g'); //  /[ὠ1-ὤF]/g -doesn't make a lot of sense  
//var reg = XRegExp('[\uD83D\uDE01-\uD83D\uDE4F]', 'g'); //Range out of order in character class
//var reg = XRegExp('\\p{L}', 'g'); //doesn't match my symbols
console.log(XRegExp.replace(str, reg, function(match){
   return encodeURIComponent(match);// here I want to have smth like that %F0%9F%98%84 to be able to map anything I want to this value and replace to it
}));
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HFZk3/)

I really don't want to bruteforce the string looking for the sequence of characters from my range. Could someone help me to find the way to do that with regexp's.

***EDITED***
Just came up with an idea of enumerating all the emoji symbols. Better than brutforce but still looking for the better idea

```
var reg = XRegExp('\uD83D\uDE01|\uD83D\uDE4F|...','g');
```

Comment: Why are you trying to match the bytes rather than the codepoints? The example you have using `'[\u1F601-\u1F64F]'` is the correct way to match these points (although the block is U+1F300-U+1F5FF).

Comment: Not only bytes, I tried many ways, but maybe I did it wrong. What would be the regexp with those codepoints? XRegExp('[\u1F300-\u1F5FF]', 'g');?

Comment: @一二三 Javascript does not support characters beyond U+FFFF natively. `\u1F601` in a Javascript string encodes two characters, U+1F60 followed by ASCII '1'. There's no way to use `U+1F601` in a character class.

Comment: Regex `/[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]/g` solved my problem. It includes not only emojis but also special characters. Referred http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744721/javascript-strings-outside-of-the-bmp

Comment: tempted to close as dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/18862256/11107541

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `\u....` notation has four hex digits, no less, no more, so it can only represent code points up to U+FFFF. Unicode characters above that are represented as pairs of surrogate code points.

So some indirect approach is needed. Cf. to [JavaScript strings outside of the BMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744721/javascript-strings-outside-of-the-bmp).

For example, you could look for code points in the range `[\uD800-\uDBFF]` (high surrogates), and when you find one, check that the next code point in the string is in the range `[\uDC00-\uDFFF]` (if not, there is a serious data error), interpret the two as a Unicode character, and replace them by whatever you wish to put there. This looks like a job for a simple loop through the string, rather than a regular expression.

Comment: Thx. But that is almost what I came to in my edited version of the question. I really want to avoid loops, cause I'm working with my string each time it is changed. But you pushed me to idea to use XRegExp('[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]','g') That would be pretty enough for me, I guess.

Answer (score 11):

This is somewhat old, but I was looking into this problem <strike>and it seems Bradley Momberger has posted a nice solution to it here: http://airhadoken.github.io/2015/04/22/javascript-string-handling-emoji.html</strike>

The regex he proposes is:

```
/[\uD800-\uDFFF]./ // This matches emoji
```

This regex matches the head surrogate, which is used by emojis, and the charracter following the head surrogate (which is assumed to be the tail surrogate). Thus, all emojis should be matched correctly and with

```
.replace(/[\uD800-\uDFFF]./g,'')
```

you should be able to remove all emojis.

<strike>**Edit:** Better regex found. The above regex misses some emojis.</strike>

But there is a reddit post with a version, for which i cannot find an emoji, that is excepted from the rule.
The reddit is here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/4vhf2f/how_to_regex_emojis_in_tasker_for_search_match_or/
And the regex is:

```
/[\uD83C-\uDBFF\uDC00-\uDFFF]+/
```

To match all occurences, use the g modifier:

```
/[\uD83C-\uDBFF\uDC00-\uDFFF]+/g
```

**Second Edit**: As CodeToad pointed out correctly, ✨ is not recognized by the above Regex, because it's in the dingbats block (thanks to air_hadoken).

The lodash library came up with an excellent Emoji Regex block:

```
(?:[\u2700-\u27bf]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff])[\ufe0e\ufe0f]?(?:[\u0300-\u036f\ufe20-\ufe23\u20d0-\u20f0]|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?(?:\u200d(?:[^\ud800-\udfff]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff])[\ufe0e\ufe0f]?(?:[\u0300-\u036f\ufe20-\ufe23\u20d0-\u20f0]|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?)*
```

Kevin Scott nicely put together, what this regex covers in his [Blog Post](https://thekevinscott.com/emojis-in-javascript/#writing-a-regular-expression). Spoiler: it includes dingbats

Comment: this is the best one I tested so far. though it  misses this emoji :✨

Comment: @CodeToad ✨ ("sparkles") is from the dingbats block, which can be represented in UTF-16 without a surrogate pair.  If you wanted to catch those as well, you'd need to check for `/[\u2700-\u27BF][\uFE0E-\uFE0F]?/` (the latter range is for a possible variant selector)

Comment: Edited to new Regex from lodash, which also includes the dingbats block.

Answer (score 8):

maybe you can take a look of this article: http://crocodillon.com/blog/parsing-emoji-unicode-in-javascript

the emoji unicode from `\u1F601` to `\u1F64F`

translate to javascript's utf-16 is `\ud83d\ude00` to `\ud83d\ude4f`

the first char is always `\ud83d`.

so the reg is out:

```
/\ud83d[\ude00-\ude4f]/g
```

hope this can make some help

Comment: That's work nicely at the end of 2021, thanks

Answer (score 5):

1. /\ud83d[\ude00-\ude4f]/g

not including all emojis like :        , see http://getemoji.com/ and try your regex https://regex101.com/

2. /[\uD83C-\uDBFF\uDC00-\uDFFF]+/g

not including all emojis like : ⛑ ☕️ ☁️☄️ ☀️☃️ ⛄️ ❄️ ☹️☺️⛩⛱™️ ©️ ®️ 〰️ ➰ ➿

3. Even this regex does not allow you to remove  all emojis...        :

https://github.com/nizaroni/emoji-strip/blob/master/dist/emoji-strip.js#L79

> Then, can you say why you think these regex is bad to remove all exotic characters and emojis ?

```
/[\u1000-\uFFFF]+/g
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove all possible emojis:

```
new RegExp('[\u1000-\uFFFF]+', 'g');
```

Comment: Can you say why -1 ?

Comment: This regex is usefull to remove all exotic Characters as emojis, including those of foreign languages. I'm french developper, I would only have UTF-8 characteres for web txt.  What characters could this regex remove in excess?

Answer (score 0):

Below regex pattern worked for me in java.

```
"[\ud83c\udc00-\ud83c\udfff]|[\ud83d\udc00-\ud83d\udfff]|[\u2600-\u27ff]"
```

As java String uses UTF-16 encoding and as emoji's are above 0xFFFF as well, this regex pattern consider surrogate pairs to identify emojis.

Answer (score 0):

For fun : Solution to remove special characters without using regexp

```
const str = "abcdefgehijkz Раз, два три! 1234567809 -ab A Z & é è Ö â                   ☺️                               ☹️                                                          -axxb-"


/********* with regExp ***********/
let startTime = new Date().getTime();
let resp = str.replace(new RegExp('[\u00FF-\uFFFF]+','g'), '');
console.log(resp);
console.log(new Date().getTime() - startTime);


/********* without regExp ***********/
startTime = new Date().getTime();
resp = Array.from(str, x => {
  let theUnicode = x.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
  while (theUnicode.length < 4) {
    theUnicode = '0' + theUnicode;
  }
  if (theUnicode < '00ff') { 
    return x;
  }
}).join('');
console.log(resp);
console.log(new Date().getTime() - startTime);
```

Answer (score -3):

emoji's in range of U+1F600 to U+1F64F

you can use this line in your script for sending with Json:

```
text.replace(/[\u1F60-\u1F64]|[\u2702-\u27B0]|[\u1F68-\u1F6C]|[\u1F30-\u1F70]{\u2600-\u26ff]/g, "");
```

Answer (score -3):

May be you should use replace in such way?

```
reg = str.replace(new RegExp('','g'),'');
```

Try out https://github.com/iLeonidze/emoji.js

Comment: The correct solution should handle the character _range_ of emojis, not just one.