# Pass emoji value to input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, emoji

I have an emoji picker in my website. When I click on an emoji than I need to pass that value to input field. I tried passing like this:

```
document.getElementById('chat_input').value = "&#x2714;";
```

Bud when I do like this, it is showing as a simple string in input. I need it to display as an emoji. Please help me fix it.

Comment: you need to show an emoticon inside input type text ?

Comment: Use an editable div perhaps?

Comment: yes editable div should be used for this approach rather than input elements

Comment: Just a side note: You should probably use `+=` instead of `=` to append the Emoji

Comment: Check out the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312364/printing-emojis-with-javascript-and-html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Cant we do it with a input element. I need to implement it in a chat box.