# Unicode value in template literal for emoji

Tags: javascript, unicode, emoji, template-literals

When I try to use a string template to generate an emoji I get an error.

How to achieve this purpose?

**Javascript code:**

```
const unifiedValue = '1F60E';
const emoji = `\u{${ unifiedValue }}`;
```

**Javascript error:**

> SyntaxError: Invalid escape sequence in template

Of course if I use the value directly it works, but that would be error-prone + thousands lines of code with hundreds of `if` conditions.

**Developer console:**

```
'\u{1F60E}'
```

**Console Output:**
    ""

Comment: You can check the below answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22315491/8609245

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`fromCodePoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint) function.

**Here is a wroking solution**

```js
const unifiedValue = '1F60E';

var emoji = `0x${unifiedValue}`;
emoji = String.fromCodePoint(emoji);

console.log(emoji);
```

Also keep in mind that our "beloved" internet explorer does not support it :/

[image]

**EDIT**

```js
const unifiedValue = '1F60E';

var emoji = parseInt(unifiedValue, 16);

emoji = String.fromCodePoint(emoji);

console.log(emoji);
```

Comment: much beloved internet explorer is not important for us :) this worked great! thank you

Comment: Don't use `\`0x${unifiedValue}\``. Just use `parseInt(unifiedValue, 16)`.

Comment: @Bergi Good point, edited answer

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is you used template quote. You must use double backslash in template quote.

```
const emoji = `\u{${ unifiedValue }}`;
```

Instead of this

```
const emoji = `\\u{${ unifiedValue }}`;
```

Comment: But it returns string: `\u{1F60E}` instead of emoticon

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski is right, double quote would espace backlash and return string `\u{1F60E}` instead, not 