# How get real char code from an emoji in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, emoji, fromcharcode

I have, for example, this emoji:

... and i want to get your char code. i tried this:

```js
var emoji = ""
var char_code = emoji.charCodeAt()
console.log(emoji,char_code)
```

But when using String's `fromCharCode` method, I don't get the original emoji:

```js
var emoji = ""
var char_code = emoji.charCodeAt()
var original = String.fromCharCode(char_code)
console.log(original)
```

How can I get the original emoji from your char code? Or else how can I get your actual char code to use it in `String.fromCharCode`?

Comment: Also, for the record, this was a very well-asked question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`String.codePointAt()` and `String.fromCodePoint()` are made for this, though it is also possible to specify a UTF-16 `charCode` in legacy browsers using [surrogate keypairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF) (see the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22315491/1674992)).

```js
let emoji = "",
    charCode = emoji.charCodeAt(),
    codePoint = emoji.codePointAt();

console.log(
    'charCode:', charCode,
    String.fromCharCode(charCode)   // doesn't work =(
)

console.log(
    'codePoint:', codePoint,
    String.fromCodePoint(codePoint) // there we go!
);
```