# Combine whitelist and blacklist in javascript regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having problems constructing a regex that will allow the full range of UTF-8 characters with the exception of 2 characters: `_` and `?`

So the whitelist is: `^[\u0000-\uFFFF]` and the blacklist is: `^[^_%]`

I need to combine these into one expression.

I have tried the following code, but does not work the way I had hoped:

```
var input = "this%";
var patrn = /[^\u0000-\uFFFF&&[^_%]]/g;
if (input.match(patrn) == "" || input.match(patrn) == null) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

input: this%

actual output: `true`

desired output: `false`

Answer (score 1):

Use negative lookahead:

```
(?!_blacklist_)_whitelist_
```

In this case:

```
^(?:(?![_%])[\u0000-\uFFFF])*$
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, one of these should be enough:

```
/^[^_%]*$/.test(str);
!/[_%]/.test(str);
```

Comment: Won't this match stuff beyond \uFFFF though, like ?

Comment: @Siguza In JS, `` is `\uD83D\uDCA9`, both of which are in the `\u0000-\uFFFF` range

Answer (score 1):

Underscore is \u005F and percent is \u0025. You can simply alter the range to exclude these two characters:

```
^[\u0000-\u0024\u0026-\u005E\u0060-\uFFFF]
```

This will be just as fast as the original regex.

---

But I don't think that you are going to get the result you *really* want this way. JS can only go up to `\uFFFF`, anything past that will be two characters technically.

According to [here](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode), the following code returns false:

```
/^.$/.test('')
```

You need to have a different way to see if you have characters outside that range. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3759300) gives the following code:

```
String.prototype.getCodePointLength= function() {
    return this.length-this.split(/[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]/g).length+1;
};
```

Simply put, if the number returned by that is not the same as the number returned by `.length()` you have a surrogate pair (and thus you should return false).

If your input passes that test, you can run it up against another regex to avoid all the characters between `\u0000-\uFFFF` that you want to avoid.

Comment: thanks, this is a qood quick fix, but this might not be maintainable if the blacklist grows. I really need to understand how to combine the whitelist and the blacklist expressions. It seems to work in java, but does not behave the same in javascript

Comment: @OneXer I have updated my answer. I think the problem is the approach you are taking.